# How Do I Choose Between a Hash Table and a Trie (Prefix Tree)?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, hashtable, trie

So if I have to choose between a hash table or a prefix tree what are the discriminating factors that would lead me to choose one over the other. From my own naive point of view it seems as though using a trie has some extra overhead since it isn't stored as an array but that in terms of run time (assuming the longest key is the longest english word) it can be essentially O(1) (in relation to the upper bound). Maybe the longest english word is 50 characters?

Hash tables are instant look up *once you get the index*. Hashing the key to get the index however seems like it could easily take near 50 steps.

Can someone provide me a more experienced perspective on this? Thanks!

Comment: It's worth noting that a redix tree is more efficient than a plain trie because you don't need a new branch for every string byte. Also, redix trees provide support for "fuzzy" searches better than hash tables because you're looking at individual bits when working down the path. For example `00110010` might be the input byte, but you want to include the match `00111010` which is only one bit removed.

Answer (score 142, accepted):

Advantages of tries:

The basics:

- Predictable O(k) lookup time where k is the size of the key
- Lookup can take less than k time if it's not there
- Supports ordered traversal
- No need for a hash function
- Deletion is straightforward

New operations:

- You can quickly look up prefixes of keys, enumerate all entries with a given prefix, etc.

Advantages of linked structure:

- If there are many common prefixes, the space they require is shared.
- Immutable tries can share structure. Instead of updating a trie in place, you can build a new one that's different only along one branch, elsewhere pointing into the old trie. This can be useful for concurrency, multiple simultaneous versions of a table, etc.
- An immutable trie is compressible. That is, it can share structure on the *suffixes* as well, by hash-consing.

Advantages of hashtables:

- Everyone knows hashtables, right? Your system will already have a nice well-optimized implementation, faster than tries for most purposes.
- Your keys need not have any special structure.
- More space-efficient than the obvious linked trie structure (**see comments below**)

Comment: can not quite agree with "More space-efficient than the obvious linked trie structure" -- in a general hash table implementation, it occupies a much larger space to contain keys, while in tries, each node represents a word. In this sense, tries are more space-efficient.

Comment: how about accesing data from one structure vs the other? I'm thinking cache and location

Comment: @galactica, that conflicts with my experience: for example, in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327223/memory-efficient-alternatives-to-python-dictionaries/327295#327295) of all the structures I measured for space, a trie fared the worst. This makes sense since a pointer is much larger than a byte. Yes, the sharing of prefixes helps, but it must overcome a lot of overhead to reach parity. A more space-efficient representation can help a lot, but then we're no longer talking about the obvious linked structure.

Comment: @DariusBacon handling telephone numbering plans seems like a reasonable scenario for tries. Sample scenario: telephone number to carrier matching incl. numbers ported from one carrier to another. For usual dictionaries it may depend on the language (Mandarin vs English), you'd need n-grams and/or other statistical data. For a rhyme book, a suffix tree also seems a good option.

Comment: The diversity of the data to lookup matters a lot. If a large percentage of your data values are unique, your space complexity will increase over the hash because of the use of additional null pointers.

Comment: Do tries necessarily support ordered traversal?  It seems to me like you need to add some support structures to traverse them at all without scanning the sparse array of child nodes

Comment: For that matter, deletion is a little tricky in that you need possibly recursively work your way up deleting parents

Answer (score 50):

It all depends on what problem you're trying to solve.  If all you need to do is insertions and lookups, go with a hash table.  If you need to solve more complex problems such as prefix-related queries, then a trie might be the better solution.

Comment: if hash table and trie have the same complexity on query, O(k) for k length string why should we go for hash? could you please explain?

Comment: In my opinion a hash table does _calculations_ on the string input, whereas a trie does _address lookups_ on the string input. The address lookups might miss the cache, whereas calculations are done much faster I think as they don't hit the cache. That is my rationalization haha.

Answer (score 37):

Everyone knows *hash table* and its uses, but it is not exactly constant look up time; it depends on how big the hash table is, and the computational complexity of the hash function.

Creating huge hash tables for efficient lookup is not an elegant solution in most of the industrial scenarios where even small latency/scalability matters (e.g.: high frequency trading). You have to care about the data structures to optimize the space it takes up in memory in order to reduce cache misses.

A very good example where a trie better suits the requirements is messaging middleware: You have a million subscribers and publishers of messages to various categories (in JMS terms - Topics or exchanges), in such cases if you want to filter out messages based on topics (which are actually strings), you definitely do not want to create a hash table for the million subscriptions with millions of topics. A better approach is to store the topics in a trie, so when filtering is done based on topic match, its complexity is independent of the number of topics/subscriptions/publishers (only depends on the length of string). I like it because you can be creative with this data structure to optimize space requirements and hence have lower cache misses.

Answer (score 14):

Use a tree:

1. If you need auto complete feature
2. Find all words beginning with 'a' or 'axe' so on.
3. A suffix tree is a special form of a tree. Suffix trees have a whole list of advantages that hash cannot cover.

Answer (score 6):

There's something I haven't seen anyone mention explicitly that I think is important to keep in mind.  Both hash tables and tries of various kinds will typically have `O(k)` operations, where `k` is the length of the string in bits (or equivalently in chars).

This is assuming you have a good hash function.  If you don't want "farm" and "farm animals" to hash to the same value, then the hash function will have to use all the bits of the key, and so hashing "farm animals" should take about twice as long as "farm" (unless you're in some sort of rolling hash scenario, but there are somewhat similar operation-saving scenarios with tries too).  And with a vanilla trie, it's clear why inserting "farm animals" will take about twice as long as just "farm".  In the long run it's true with compressed tries as well.

Answer (score 6):

Insertion and lookup on a trie is linear with the lengh of the input string O(s).

A hash will give you a O(1) for lookup ans insertion, but first you have to calculate the hash based on the input string which again is O(s).

Conclussion, the asymptotic time complexity is linear in both cases.

The trie has some more overhead from data perspective, but you can choose a compressed trie which will put you again, more or less on a tie with the hash table.

To break the tie ask yourself this question: Do i need to lookup for full words only? Or do I need to return all words matching a prefix? (As in a predictive text input system ). For the first case, go for a hash. It is simpler and cleaner code. Easier to test and maintain. For a more ellaborated use case where prefixes or sufixes matter, go for a trie.

And if you do it just for fun, implementing a trie would put a Sunday afternoon to a good use.

Comment: "A hash will give you a O(1) for lookup ans insertion, but first you have to calculate the hash based on the input string which again is O(s)." Thanks for explaining this!

Comment: Calculating hash function is not O(s). It's actually O(1). You don't need all the bits of the string to compute it, some of them (a constant number of them) is enough.

Answer (score 2):

**HashTable** implementation is space efficient as compared to basic **Trie** implementation. But with strings, ordering is necessary in most of the practical applications. But HashTable totally disturbs the lexographical order. Now, if your application is doing operations based on lexographical order (like partial search, all strings with given prefix, all words in sorted order), you should use Tries. For only lookup, HashTable should be used (as arguably, it gives minimum lookup time).

**P.S.:** Other than these, **Ternary Search Trees (TSTs)** would be an excellent choice. Its lookup time is more than HashTable, but is time-efficient in all other operations. Also, its more space efficient than tries.

Answer (score -3):

Some (usually embedded, real-time) applications require that the processing time be independent of the data.  In that case, a hash table can guarantee a known execution time, while a trie varies based on the data.

Comment: Most hash tables don't guarantee a known execution time - the worst case is O(n), if every element collides and gets chained

Comment: For any data set, you can compute a perfect hash function that will guarantee O(1) lookups for that data. Of course, computing the perfect hash ain't free.

Comment: Also, chaining is not the only way to handle collisions; there are all sorts of interesting, clever ways to handle this—cuckoo hashing (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuckoo_hashing) for one—and the best choice depends on the needs of the client code.

Comment: didn't know about cuckoo hashing and its relation to the bloom filter, will make for an interesting read, thanks!

Comment: Don't forget about Robin-hood Hashing, which is superior for cache and variance. http://sebastiansylvan.com/2013/05/08/robin-hood-hashing-should-be-your-default-hash-table-implementation/ http://codecapsule.com/2013/11/11/robin-hood-hashing/

Comment: That seems absolutely backwards, Tries have STRONGER guarantees about the asymptotics than dicts do, tries are absolute worse case `O(k)` (where k is key size) for any operation, whereas an imperfect hash algorithm or really bad luck can break that bound for dicts.