# What does sys.intern() do and when should it be used?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, memory, memory-management, sys

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327223/) about memory management of dictionaries, which mentions the **intern** function. What exactly does it do, and when would it be used?

**To give an example:** if I have a set called **seen**, that contains tuples in the form (string1,string2), which I use to check for duplicates, would storing (intern(string1),intern(string2)) improve performance w.r.t. memory or speed?

Comment: I would like to put here this article, which also gives interesting examples and concepts regarding this very good question: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/optimization-in-python-the-interning-technique-for-improved-performance-3ff14d376176

Answer (score 96, accepted):

*From the [Python 3](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/sys.html?highlight=sys.intern#sys.intern) documentation*:

```
sys.intern(string)
```

> Enter string in the table of “interned” strings and return the
>   interned string – which is string itself or a copy. Interning strings
>   is useful to gain a little performance on dictionary lookup – if the
>   keys in a dictionary are interned, and the lookup key is interned, the
>   key comparisons (after hashing) can be done by a pointer compare
>   instead of a string compare. Normally, the names used in Python
>   programs are automatically interned, and the dictionaries used to hold
>   module, class or instance attributes have interned keys.
>
> Interned strings are not immortal; you must keep a reference to the
>   return value of intern() around to benefit from it.

*Clarification*:

As the documentation suggests, the `sys.intern` function is intended to be used for **performance optimization**.

The `sys.intern` function maintains a table of **interned** strings. When you attempt to intern a string, the function looks it up in the table and:

1. If the string does not exists (hasn't been interned yet) the function saves
   it in the table and returns it from the interned strings table.

   ```
   >>> import sys
   >>> a = sys.intern('why do pangolins dream of quiche')
   >>> a
   'why do pangolins dream of quiche'
   ```

   In the above example, `a` holds the interned string. Even though it is not visible, the `sys.intern` function has saved the `'why do pangolins dream of quiche'` string object in the interned strings table.
2. If the string exists (has been interned) the function returns it from the
   interned strings table.

   ```
   >>> b = sys.intern('why do pangolins dream of quiche')
   >>> b
   'why do pangolins dream of quiche'
   ```

   Even though it is not immediately visible, because the string `'why do pangolins dream of quiche'` has been interned before, `b` holds now the same string object as `a`.

   ```
   >>> b is a
   True
   ```

   If we create the same string without using intern, we end up with two different string objects that have the same value.

   ```
   >>> c = 'why do pangolins dream of quiche'
   >>> c is a
   False
   >>> c is b
   False
   ```

By using `sys.intern` you ensure that you never create two string objects that have the same value—when you request the creation of a second string object with the same value as an existing string object, you receive a reference to the pre-existing string object. This way, you are **saving memory**. Also, string objects comparison is now **very efficient** because it is carried out by comparing the memory addresses of the two string objects instead of their content.

Comment: If we write the code in a `.py` file and do it we get `c is a` as `True`. Why is that?

Comment: @ShashankSingh my understanding is that when the python file is compiled into a PYC file it creates a list of constants in the file, in this case the string, and everywhere it shows up instead of recreating the string refers to the constant. So when the file is read all occurrences of assigning the string 'why do ...' assign to the same instance of the string.

Answer (score 24):

Essentially intern looks up (or stores if not present) the string in a collection of interned strings, so all interned instances will share the same identity.  You trade the one-time cost of looking up this string for faster comparisons (the compare can return True after just checking for identity, rather than having to compare each character), and reduced memory usage.

However, python will [automatically intern strings that are small, or look like identifiers](http://guilload.com/python-string-interning/), so you may find you get no improvement because your strings are already being interned behind the scenes.  For example:

```
>>> a = 'abc'; b = 'abc'
>>> a is b
True
```

In the past, one disadvantage was that interned strings were permanent.  Once interned, the string memory was never freed even after all references were dropped.  I think this is no longer the case for more recent versions of python though.

Comment: *CPython* will automatically intern strings that are small — it's an implementation behaviour and isn't guaranteed to be true of all implementations (but likely is).

Comment: CPython will automatically intern strings that are small, but only if they're constant expressions in your code, not strings created at run-time. See stackoverflow.com/questions/15541404/python-string-interning.

Answer (score 10):

They weren't talking about keyword `intern` because there is no such thing in Python. They were talking about [non-essential built-in function `intern`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=intern#intern). Which in py3k has been moved to [`sys.intern`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/sys.html?highlight=sys#sys.intern). Docs have an exhaustive description.

Comment: Correct link to intern() documentation for post-Python 2 times: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#intern

Answer (score 4):

It returns a canonical instance of the string.

Therefore if you have many string instances that are equal you save memory, and in addition you can also compare canonicalized strings by identity instead of equality which is faster.