# Immutable vs Mutable types

Tags: python, types, immutability, mutable

I'm confused on what an immutable type is. I know the `float` object is considered to be immutable, with this type of example from my book:

```
class RoundFloat(float):
    def __new__(cls, val):
        return float.__new__(cls, round(val, 2))
```

Is this considered to be immutable because of the class structure / hierarchy?, meaning `float` is at the top of the class and is its own method call. Similar to this type of example (even though my book says `dict` is mutable):

```
class SortedKeyDict(dict):
    def __new__(cls, val):
        return dict.__new__(cls, val.clear())
```

Whereas something mutable has methods inside the class, with this type of example:

```
class SortedKeyDict_a(dict):
    def example(self):
        return self.keys()
```

---

Also, for the last `class(SortedKeyDict_a)`, if I pass this type of set to it:

```
d = (('zheng-cai', 67), ('hui-jun', 68),('xin-yi', 2))
```

without calling the `example` method, it returns a dictionary. The `SortedKeyDict` with `__new__` flags it as an error. I tried passing integers to the `RoundFloat` class with `__new__` and it flagged no errors.

Comment: You can also check out [List assignment with \[:\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677275/list-assignment-with/7677417#7677417) and [python when to use copy.copy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7046971/python-when-to-use-copy-copy/7047061#7047061) which I also answered for more info about mutability.

Answer (score 243):

What? Floats are immutable? But can't I do

```
x = 5.0
x += 7.0
print x # 12.0
```

Doesn't that "mut" x?

Well you agree strings are immutable right? But you can do the same thing.

```
s = 'foo'
s += 'bar'
print s # foobar
```

The value of the variable changes, but it changes by changing what the variable refers to. A mutable type can change that way, and it can *also* change "in place".

Here is the difference.

```
x = something # immutable type
print x
func(x)
print x # prints the same thing

x = something # mutable type
print x
func(x)
print x # might print something different

x = something # immutable type
y = x
print x
# some statement that operates on y
print x # prints the same thing

x = something # mutable type
y = x
print x
# some statement that operates on y
print x # might print something different
```

Concrete examples

```
x = 'foo'
y = x
print x # foo
y += 'bar'
print x # foo

x = [1, 2, 3]
y = x
print x # [1, 2, 3]
y += [3, 2, 1]
print x # [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1]

def func(val):
    val += 'bar'

x = 'foo'
print x # foo
func(x)
print x # foo

def func(val):
    val += [3, 2, 1]

x = [1, 2, 3]
print x # [1, 2, 3]
func(x)
print x # [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: What you explain means to me: mutable variables are passed by reference, immutable variables are passed by value. Is this correct ?

Comment: Almost, but not exactly. Technically, all variables are passed by reference in Python, but have a semantics more like pass by value in C. A counterexample to your analogy is if you do `def f(my_list): my_list = [1, 2, 3]`. With pass-by-reference in C, the value of the argument could change by calling that function. In Python, that function doesn't do anything. `def f(my_list): my_list[:] = [1, 2, 3]` would do something.

Comment: Mutable types can be changed in place. Immutable types can not change in place. That's the way python sees the world. It is regardless of how variables are passed to functions.

Comment: As said in answer before, use id()
<code>- >>> d = 10
- >>> id(d)
- 30483204
- >>> d+=10
- >>> id(d)
- 30483084
- >>> l = []
- >>> id(l)
- 35637088
- >>> l.append(10)
- >>> id(l)
- 35637088</code>

Comment: The key difference between Python's semantics and C++ pass-by-reference semantics is that assignment is not mutation in Python, and it is in C++. (But of course that's complicated by the fact that augmented assignment, like `a += b` sometimes _is_ mutation. And the fact that assignment to part of a larger object sometimes means mutation of that larger object, just never mutation of the part—e.g., `a[0] = b` doesn't mutate `a[0]`, but it probably does mutate `a`… Which is why it may be better not to try to put things in terms of C++ and instead just describe what Python does in its own terms…)

Comment: @morningstar: FYI, you're almost certainly thinking of C++ references. C does not have references, only pointers (and "simulated references," i.e. arrays). The C version of that code won't do anything either: `void f(list* my_list) { my_list = (list*) malloc(sizeof(list)); }` would not change the argument, just the (local) parameter.

Comment: This is a somewhat misleading answer. For example: `x = ([],2) #Immutable type`, then `func(x)` then `print x` might print something different, for example `(['a', 'b', 'c'], 2)`.

Comment: I found this answer misleading because it does not use id(), which is essential for understanding what immutable means.

Comment: @morningstar, 'Doesn't that "mut" x?' - leaves the impression that floats are mutable while the fact is the opposite one. I think the style of answer might confuse a newbie.

Comment: Absolutely incorrect comments here: python never uses call by value nor call by reference. Assignment statements in Python use *reference semantics*, but the evaluation strategy is always call by object sharing (which is **not** call by reference)

Comment: Is there a good reference (book, online tutorial, etc.) that REALLY explains all of this call by reference, call by value, call by object sharing STUFF? I'm new to Python, and haven't done much programming in general (just numerical computing for my research) but I really want to learn all of these concepts, so that I can understand what these languages are doing behind the scenes, so that I understand why something that I do in one language doesn't seem to work in another language.

Answer (score 198):

You have to understand that Python represents all its data as objects. Some of these objects like lists and dictionaries are mutable, meaning you can change their content without changing their identity. Other objects like integers, floats, strings and tuples are objects that can not be changed.
An easy way to understand that is if you have a look at an objects ID.

Below you see a string that is immutable. You can not change its content. It will raise a `TypeError` if you try to change it. Also, if we assign new content, a new object is created instead of the contents being modified.

```
>>> s = "abc"
>>> id(s)
4702124
>>> s[0] 
'a'
>>> s[0] = "o"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
>>> s = "xyz"
>>> id(s)
4800100
>>> s += "uvw"
>>> id(s)
4800500
```

You can do that with a list and it will not change the objects identity

```
>>> i = [1,2,3]
>>> id(i)
2146718700
>>> i[0] 
1
>>> i[0] = 7
>>> id(i)
2146718700
```

To read more about Python's data model you could have a look at the Python language reference:

- [Python 2 datamodel](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html)
- [Python 3 datamodel](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html)

Comment: +1 For the link to the Python docs. However it took me some time until I realized that today you need to differentiate bewteen Python 2 & 3 - I updated the answer to emphasize that.

Answer (score 117):

Common immutable type:

1. numbers: `int()`, `float()`, `complex()`
2. immutable sequences: `str()`, `tuple()`, `frozenset()`, `bytes()`

Common mutable type (almost everything else):

1. mutable sequences: `list()`, `bytearray()`
2. set type: `set()`
3. mapping type: `dict()`
4. classes, class instances
5. etc.

One trick to quickly test if a type is mutable or not, is to use `id()` built-in function.

Examples, using on integer,

```
>>> i = 1
>>> id(i)
***704
>>> i += 1
>>> i
2
>>> id(i)
***736 (different from ***704)
```

using on list,

```
>>> a = [1]
>>> id(a)
***416
>>> a.append(2)
>>> a
[1, 2]
>>> id(a)
***416 (same with the above id)
```

Comment: Well explained. Liked the concept of checking by `id()`. +1.

Comment: Actually the use of `id()` is misleading here.  A given object will always have the same id during its lifetime, but different objects that exist at different times may have the same id due to garbage collection.

Comment: In case anybody else is interested in further information on the comment by @augurar, here is a related thread I found that might be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52096582/how-unique-is-pythons-id

Answer (score 40):

First of all, whether a class has methods or what it's class structure is has nothing to do with mutability.

`int`s and `float`s are *immutable*. If I do

```
a = 1
a += 5
```

It points the name `a` at a `1` somewhere in memory on the first line. On the second line, it looks up that `1`, adds `5`, gets `6`, then points `a` at that `6` in memory -- it didn't *change* the `1` to a `6` in any way. The same logic applies to the following examples, using other *immutable* types:

```
b = 'some string'
b += 'some other string'
c = ('some', 'tuple')
c += ('some', 'other', 'tuple')
```

For *mutable* types, I can do thing that actallly *change the value where it's stored in memory*. With:

```
d = [1, 2, 3]
```

I've created a list of the locations of `1`, `2`, and `3` in memory. If I then do

```
e = d
```

I just point `e` to the *same `list`* `d` points at. I can then do:

```
e += [4, 5]
```

And the list that both `e` and `d` points at will be updated to also have the locations of `4` and `5` in memory.

If I go back to an *immutable* type and do that with a `tuple`:

```
f = (1, 2, 3)
g = f
g += (4, 5)
```

Then `f` still only points to the *original `tuple`* -- you've pointed `g` at an *entirely new `tuple`*.

Now, with your example of

```
class SortedKeyDict(dict):
    def __new__(cls, val):
        return dict.__new__(cls, val.clear())
```

Where you pass

```
d = (('zheng-cai', 67), ('hui-jun', 68),('xin-yi', 2))
```

(which is a `tuple` of `tuples`) as `val`, you're getting an error because `tuple`s don't have a `.clear()` method -- you'd have to pass `dict(d)` as `val` for it to work, in which case you'll get an empty `SortedKeyDict` as a result.

Answer (score 30):

## Difference between Mutable and Immutable objects

### Definitions

**Mutable object**: Object that can be changed after creating it.
**Immutable object**: Object that cannot be changed after creating it.

In Python if you change the value of the immutable object it will create a new object.

### Mutable Objects

Here are the objects in Python that are of mutable type:

1. `list`
2. `Dictionary`
3. `Set`
4. `bytearray`
5. `user defined classes`

### Immutable Objects

Here are the objects in Python that are of immutable type:

1. `int`
2. `float`
3. `decimal`
4. `complex`
5. `bool`
6. `string`
7. `tuple`
8. `range`
9. `frozenset`
10. `bytes`

## Some Unanswered Questions

**Question**: **Is string an immutable type?**
**Answer**: **yes**  it is, but can you explain this:
**Proof 1**:

```py
a = "Hello"
a +=" World"
print a
```

**Output**

```
"Hello World"
```

In the above example the string got once created as "Hello" then changed to "Hello World". This implies that the string is of the mutable type. But it is not when we check its identity to see whether it is of a mutable type or not.

```py
a = "Hello"
identity_a = id(a)
a += " World"
new_identity_a = id(a)
if identity_a != new_identity_a:
    print "String is Immutable"
```

**Output**

```
String is Immutable
```

**Proof 2**:

```py
a = "Hello World"
a[0] = "M"
```

**Output**

```
TypeError 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

**Question**: **Is Tuple an immutable type?**
**Answer**: **yes**,  it is.
**Proof 1**:

```py
tuple_a = (1,)
tuple_a[0] = (2,)
print a
```

**Output**

```
'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

Comment: In [46]: a ="Hello"

In [47]: id(a)
Out[47]: 140071263880128

In [48]: a = a.replace("H","g")

In [49]: a
Out[49]: 'gello'

In [50]: id(a)
Out[50]: 140071263881040

Comment: would you care to proof your item assignment issue to my given above example

Comment: item assignment is not issue in immutable types. In your case you are  changing the string a but in memory its assigning to a new variable. Item assignment in my case will not change the memory of variable like in case of list or dictionary. if you are doing replace you are creating a new variable not modifying existing variable

Comment: @ArgusMalware in your case, two id are equals because of the first one recycled by GC, so the second one re-use the memory.

Answer (score 29):

If you're coming to Python from another language (except one that's a lot like Python, like Ruby), and insist on understanding it in terms of that other language, here's where people usually get confused:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> a = 2 # I thought int was immutable, but I just changed it?!
```

In Python, assignment is not mutation in Python.

In C++, if you write `a = 2`, you're calling `a.operator=(2)`, which will mutate the object stored in `a`. (And if there *was* no object stored in `a`, that's an error.)

In Python, `a = 2` does nothing to whatever was stored in `a`; it just means that `2` is now stored in `a` instead. (And if there *was* no object stored in `a`, that's fine.)

---

Ultimately, this is part of an even deeper distinction.

A variable in a language like C++ is a typed location in memory. If `a` is an `int`, that means it's 4 bytes somewhere that the compiler knows is supposed to be interpreted as an `int`. So, when you do `a = 2`, it changes what's stored in those 4 bytes of memory from `0, 0, 0, 1` to `0, 0, 0, 2`. If there's another int variable somewhere else, it has its own 4 bytes.

A variable in a language like Python is a name for an object that has a life of its own. There's an object for the number `1`, and another object for the number `2`. And `a` isn't 4 bytes of memory that are represented as an `int`, it's just a name that points at the `1` object. It doesn't make sense for `a = 2` to turn the number 1 into the number 2 (that would give any Python programmer way too much power to change the fundamental workings of the universe); what it does instead is just make `a` forget the `1` object and point at the `2` object instead.

---

So, if assignment isn't a mutation, what *is* a mutation?

- Calling a method that's documented to mutate, like `a.append(b)`. (Note that these methods almost always return `None`). Immutable types do not have any such methods, mutable types usually do.
- Assigning to a part of the object, like `a.spam = b` or `a[0] = b`. Immutable types do not allow assignment to attributes or elements, mutable types usually allow one or the other.
- Sometimes using augmented assignment, like `a += b`, sometimes not. Mutable types usually mutate the value; immutable types never do, and give you a copy instead (they calculate `a + b`, then assign the result to `a`).

But if assignment isn't mutation, how is assigning to part of the object mutation? That's where it gets tricky. `a[0] = b` does *not* mutate `a[0]` (again, unlike C++), but it *does* mutate `a` (unlike C++, except indirectly).

All of this is why it's probably better *not* to try to put Python's semantics in terms of a language you're used to, and instead learn Python's semantics on their own terms.

Comment: Say a = 'hi'. a[0] = 'f' will have 'print a' print out 'fi' (Am I right so far?), so when you say that it doesn't mutate a[0], rather a, what does that mean? Does a[n] also have it's own place now, and changing its value points it to a different value?

Answer (score 17):

Whether an object is mutable or not depends on its type. This doesn't depend on whether or not it has certain methods, nor on the structure of the class hierarchy.

User-defined types (i.e. classes) are generally mutable. There are some exceptions, such as simple sub-classes of an immutable type. Other immutable types include some built-in types such as `int`, `float`, `tuple` and `str`, as well as some Python classes implemented in C.

A general explanation from [the "Data Model" chapter in the Python Language Reference"](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types):

> The value of some objects can change. Objects whose value can change
> are said to be mutable; objects whose value is unchangeable once they
> are created are called immutable.
>
> (The value of an immutable container
> object that contains a reference to a mutable object can change when
> the latter’s value is changed; however the container is still
> considered immutable, because the collection of objects it contains
> cannot be changed. So, immutability is not strictly the same as having
> an unchangeable value, it is more subtle.)
>
> An object’s mutability is
> determined by its type; for instance, numbers, strings and tuples are
> immutable, while dictionaries and lists are mutable.

Comment: +1 Note though that only some extension types (you may want to review your definition of that, all of Python's builtin types are implemented in C) are immutable. Others (most, I'd dare say) are perfectly mutable.

Comment: @delnan What do you call _"extensions types"_ ?

Comment: @eyquem: I used the term "extension types" incorrectly in my answer, and delnan was referring to that. After his comment I revised my answer and avoided using this term.

Answer (score 10):

A mutable object has to have at least a method able to mutate the object. For example, the `list` object has the `append` method, which will actually mutate the object:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> a.append('hello') # `a` has mutated but is still the same object
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 'hello']
```

but the class `float` has no method to mutate a float object. You can do:

```
>>> b = 5.0 
>>> b = b + 0.1
>>> b
5.1
```

but the `=` operand is not a method. It just make a bind between the variable and whatever is to the right of it, nothing else. It never changes or creates objects. It is a declaration of what the variable will point to, since now on.

When you do `b = b + 0.1` the `=` operand binds the variable to a new float, wich is created with te result of  `5 + 0.1`.

When you assign a variable to an existent object, mutable or not, the `=` operand binds the variable to that object. And nothing more happens

In either case, the `=` just make the bind. It doesn't change or create objects.

When you do `a = 1.0`, the `=` operand is not wich create the float, but the `1.0` part of the line. Actually when you write `1.0` it is a shorthand for `float(1.0)` a constructor call returning a float object. (That is the reason why if you type `1.0` and press enter you get the "echo" `1.0` printed below; that is the return value of the constructor function you called)

Now, if `b` is a float and you assign `a = b`, both variables are pointing to the same object, but actually the variables can't comunicate betweem themselves, because the object is inmutable, and if you do `b += 1`, now `b` point to a new object, and `a` is still pointing to the oldone and cannot know what `b` is pointing to.

but if `c` is, let's say, a `list`, and you assign `a = c`, now `a` and `c` can "comunicate", because `list` is mutable, and if you do `c.append('msg')`, then just checking `a` you get the message.

(By the way, every object has an unique id number asociated to, wich you can get with `id(x)`. So you can check if an object is the same or not checking if its unique id has changed.)

Answer (score 5):

> A class is **immutable** if each object of that class has a fixed value upon instantiation that cannot ***SUBSEQUENTLY*** be changed

In another word change the entire value of that variable `(name)` or leave it alone.

Example:

```
my_string = "Hello world" 
my_string[0] = "h"
print my_string
```

you expected this to work and print **hello world** but this will throw the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
my_string[0] = "h"
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

The interpreter is saying : *i can't change the first character of this string*

you will have to change the whole `string` in order to make it works:

```
my_string = "Hello World" 
my_string = "hello world"
print my_string #hello world
```

check this table:

[image]

[source](https://it-ebooks24.com/ebook/data-structures-and-algorithms-in-python)

Comment: How can one modify components of a python string in a more concise way than you showed above?

Comment: @LukeDavis You could do `my_string = 'h' + my_string[1:]`. This will generate a new string called my_string, and the original my_string is gone (print `id(my_string)` to see this).
Of course that is not very flexible, for the more general case you could convert to list and back:
`l = list(my_string)`
`l[0] = 'h'`
`my_string = ''.join(l)`

Answer (score 4):

It would seem to me that **you are fighting with the question what mutable/immutable actually means**. So here is a simple explenation:

**First we need a foundation to base the explenation on.**

So think of anything that you program as a virtual object, something that is saved in a computers memory as a sequence of binary numbers. (Don't try to imagine this too hard, though.^^) Now in most computer languages you will not work with these binary numbers directly, but rather more you use an interpretation of binary numbers.

E.g. you do not think about numbers like 0x110, 0xaf0278297319 or similar, but instead you think about numbers like 6 or Strings like "Hello, world". Never the less theses numbers or Strings are an interpretation of a binary number in the computers memory. The same is true for any value of a variable.

In short: ***We*** do not **program with** actual values but with **interpretations of actual binary values.**

Now we do have interpretations that must not be changed for the sake of logic and other "neat stuff" while there are interpretations that may well be changed. For example think of the simulation of a city, in other words a program where there are many virtual objects and some of these are houses. Now may these virtual objects (the houses) be changed and can they still be considered to be the same houses? Well of course they can. Thus they are mutable: They can be changed without becoming a "completely" different object.

Now think of integers: These also are virtual objects (sequences of binary numbers in a computers memory). So if we change one of them, like incrementing the value six by one, is it still a six? Well of course not. Thus any integer is immutable.

So: ***If any change in a virtual object means that it actually becomes another virtual object, then it is called immutable.***

Final remarks:

(1) Never mix up your real-world experience of mutable and immutable with programming in a certain language:

***Every programming language has a definition of its own on which objects may be muted and which ones may not.***

So while you may now understand the difference in meaning, you still have to learn the actual implementation for each programming language. ... Indeed there might be a purpose of a language where a 6 may be muted to become a 7. Then again this would be quite some crazy or interesting stuff, like simulations of parallel universes.^^

(2) This explenation is certainly not scientific, it is meant to help you to grasp the difference between mutable and immutable.

Answer (score 4):

The goal of this answer is to create a single place to find all the good ideas about how to tell if you are dealing with mutating/nonmutating (immutable/mutable), and where possible, what to do about it?  There are times when mutation is undesirable and python's behavior in this regard can feel counter-intuitive to coders coming into it from other languages.

As per a useful post by @mina-gabriel:

- Books to read that might help:  "[Data Structures and Algorithms in Python](https://it-ebooks24.com/ebook/data-structures-and-algorithms-in-python)"
- Excerpt from that book that lists mutable/immutable types: 
  [mutable/imutable types image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3iZD.png)

Analyzing the above and combining w/ a post by @arrakëën:

*What cannot change unexpectedly?*

- scalars (variable types storing a single value) do not change unexpectedly

  - numeric examples: int(), float(), complex()
- there are some "mutable sequences":

  - str(), tuple(), frozenset(), bytes()

*What can?*

- list like objects (lists, dictionaries, sets, bytearray())
- a post on here also says classes and class instances but this may depend on what the class inherits from and/or how its built.

by "unexpectedly" I mean that programmers from other languages might not expect this behavior (with the exception or Ruby, and maybe a few other "Python like" languages).

Adding to this discussion:

This behavior is an advantage when it prevents you from accidentally populating your code with mutliple copies of memory-eating large data structures.  But when this is undesirable, how do we get around it?

With lists, the simple solution is to build a new one like so:

list2 = list(list1)

with other structures ... the solution can be trickier.  One way is to loop through the elements and add them to a new empty data structure (of the same type).

functions can mutate the original when you pass in mutable structures.  How to tell?

- There are some tests given on other comments on this thread but then there are comments indicating these tests are not full proof
- object.function() is a method of the original object but only some of these mutate.  If they return nothing, they probably do.  One would expect .append() to mutate without testing it given its name.  .union() returns the union of set1.union(set2) and does not mutate.  When in doubt, the function can be checked for a return value.  If return = None, it does not mutate.
- sorted() might be a workaround in some cases.  Since it returns a sorted version of the original, it can allow you to store a non-mutated copy before you start working on the original in other ways. However, this option assumes you don't care about the order of the original elements (if you do, you need to find another way).  In contrast .sort() mutates the original (as one might expect).

Non-standard Approaches (in case helpful):
Found this on github published under an MIT license:

- github repository under: tobgu named: pyrsistent
- What it is:  Python persistent data structure code written to be used in place of core data structures when mutation is undesirable

For custom classes, @semicolon suggests checking if there is a `__hash__` function because mutable objects should generally not have a `__hash__()` function.

This is all I have amassed on this topic for now.  Other ideas, corrections, etc. are welcome.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

One way of thinking of the difference:

Assignments to immutable objects in python can be thought of as deep copies, 
whereas assignments to mutable objects are shallow

Comment: This is incorrect.  All assignments in Python are by reference.  There is no copying involved.

Answer (score 2):

**The simplest answer:**

A mutable variable is one whose value may change in place, whereas in an immutable variable change of value will not happen in place. Modifying an immutable variable will rebuild the same variable.

**Example:**

```
>>>x = 5
```

Will create a value 5 referenced by x

x -> 5

```
>>>y = x
```

This statement will make y refer to 5 of x

x -------------> 5 <-----------y

```
>>>x = x + y
```

As x being an integer (immutable type) has been rebuild.

In the statement, the expression on RHS will result into value 10 and when this is assigned to LHS (x), x will rebuild to 10. So now

x--------->10

y--------->5

Answer (score 2):

Every time we change value of a immutable variable it basically destroy the previous instance and create a new instance of variable class

```
var = 2 #Immutable data
print(id(var))
var += 4
print(id(var))

list_a = [1,2,3] #Mutable data
print(id(list_a))
list_a[0]= 4
print(id(list_a))
```

Output:

```
9789024
9789088
140010877705856
140010877705856
```

Note:Mutable variable memory_location is change when we change the value

Answer (score 1):

**Mutable** means that **it can change/mutate**. Immutable the opposite.

Some Python data types are mutable, others not.

Let's find what are the types that fit in each category and see some examples.

---

**Mutable**

In Python there are various mutable types:

- lists
- dict
- set

Let's see the following example for `lists`.

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

If I do the following to change the first element

```
list[0] = '!'
#['!', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

It works just fine, as lists are mutable.

If we consider that list, that was changed, and assign a variable to it

```
y = list
```

And if we change an element from the list such as

```
list[0] = 'Hello'
#['Hello', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

And if one prints `y` it will give

```
['Hello', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

As both `list` and `y` are referring to the same list, and we have changed the list.

---

**Immutable**

In some programming languages one can define a constant such as the following

```
const a = 10
```

And if one calls, it would give an error

```
a = 20
```

However, that doesn't exist in Python.

In Python, however, there are various immutable types:

- None
- bool
- int
- float
- str
- tuple

Let's see the following example for `strings`.

Taking the string `a`

```
a = 'abcd'
```

We can get the first element with

```
a[0]
#'a'
```

If one tries to assign a new value to the element in the first position

```
a[0] = '!'
```

It will give an error

> 'str' object does not support item assignment

When one says += to a string, such as

```
a += 'e'
#'abcde'
```

It doesn't give an error, because it is pointing `a` to a different string.

It would be the same as the following

```
a = a + 'f'
```

And not changing the string.

*Some Pros and Cons of being immutable*

• The space in memory is known from the start. It would not require extra space.

• Usually, it makes things more efficiently. Finding, for example, the `len()` of a string is much faster, as it is part of the string object.

Answer (score 0):

in python every datatype is a class (everything is object)

```
var1 = 5
```

`var1` is the variable, a name tag pointing to an object(holds the object address, like a pointer in c)

```
id(var1) #returns the memory address storing int type object with value 5
```

`5` is the object instance of class int stored on memory

if i perform some operations on var1

```
var1 += 3
```

int ,float, string, tuple, ... are immutable. they cant change value after creation.
this will not change the object 5 stored on memory  which var1 is currently pointing to, instead it just take the value 5 of this object, add 3  making 8, then create a new int object with value 8 stored at different location and redirect var1 to the memory location of the new object

```
var1 = 5
print(id(var1))

var1 += 3
print(id(var1))
```

this prints two different  memory address storing int obj 5 and 8 respectively

for mutables types list, set, dictionary, ...

```
var1 = [1, 2, 3]
print(id(var1))

var1 += [4,5]
print(id(var1))
```

this prints same memory address, showing `var1` is still pointing to the same memory address holding an object of list type `[1, 2, 3]` at one point in time then holding same object with added elements `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` at the last print

this way, it does not  create new instance but the same obj instance was mutated to include the added elements.

immutable objects memory management

since this object can't change value after creation, changing anything means creating a new object.
python avoid creating duplicate objects by Interning.
it has a list of  objects ,objects types and its values that are in use or in memory, if you define new variable to a new immutable  object of a value,it will check its  objects list in memory, if it has object of this type with same value in memory, it just point the new variable assigned, to the obj in memory with the same value instead of creating a new one with same value.
multiple variable reuse same object in memory without any side effect to the variables referencing them, since the object value can't change.

```
var1 = 1006
print(id(var1))

var2 = 1006
print(id(var2))
```

it will print same address as both are pointing to same object even though you define the variable individually, not by aliasing `var1 = var2 = 1006` and its of immutable type

it keeps track of this object and the variables that are pointing to it, if no variable is referencing it anymore, it is passed to the garbage collector for deletion

In Fact in the default implementation of Python CPython, small integers (usually within the range of -5 to 256) are cached and reused. This optimization is known as "integer interning" When Python starts up, it creates a pool of integer objects for small values (usually from -5 to 256).
There is only one instance of each integer in the memory pool.
When you create a variable and assign it a small integer value, Python checks if the value falls within the interned range. If it does, it reuses the existing object rather than creating a new one.

This behavior is an optimization strategy aimed at reducing memory consumption and improving performance for frequently used small integers.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't read all the answers, but the selected answer is not correct and I think the author has an idea that being able to reassign a variable means that whatever datatype is mutable. That is not the case. Mutability has to do with passing by reference rather than passing by value.

Lets say you created a List

```
a = [1,2]
```

If you were to say:

```
b = a
b[1] = 3
```

Even though you reassigned a value on B, it will also reassign the value on a. Its because when you assign "b = a". You are passing the "Reference" to the object rather than a copy of the value. This is not the case with strings, floats etc. This makes list, dictionaries and the likes mutable, but booleans, floats etc immutable.

Answer (score -1):

Update: disregard my erroneous points in this answer. All variables are passed by reference. I'll fix this answer later. See this comment, and the comments below my answer: [Immutable vs Mutable types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056130/immutable-vs-mutable-types/77177223#comment33996331_8059504)

I'm choosing not to delete it while I fix it up so that I can get more feedback and corrections in the comments first.

---

Mutable types vs immutable types in Python

### 1. Summary

1. [*Mutable*](https://www.wordreference.com/definition/mutable) in plain English means *changeable.* Think: "mutation".
2. [*Immutable*](https://www.wordreference.com/definition/immutable) means *unchangeable*.
3. Python has no concept of constants. *Immutable* vs *mutable* does *not* mean *constant* vs *not constant*, respectively. Rather, it means immutable --> *shared memory (a single underlying object in memory via dynamic memory allocation, for a given literal value assigned to variables)* vs mutable --> *not shared memory (multiple underlying objects in memory via dynamic memory allocation, for a given literal value assigned to variables)*, respectively. I have more on this below, as this is quite nuanced.

   1. This, as a consequence, also means *pass by reference* (mutable) vs *pass by value* (immutable), since objects which are capable of maintaining their own unique underlying objects in memory can pass those mutable memory chunks by reference so that they can be mutated.
4. Everything in Python is an object. Even numbers, integers, float, etc. are objects. All variables are objects.
5. The mutable vs immutable objects types in Python are listed below.
6. ***Mutable* types are passed *by reference*, and cause *side effects*.**

   1. If you do `my_dict3 = my_dict2 = my_dict1 = {}`, then change `my_dict3`, it *does* also change `my_dict2` *and* `my_dict1`. This is a *side effect.* It is because each variable points to *the same* underlying object (memory blob).
   2. Again, if you *chain-assign* mutable types, each mutable variable points to *the same* underlying object in memory, since the value is passed from one variable to the next *by reference*:

      ```py
      my_dict1 = {"key": "value"}
      # Copy **by reference**, so all variables point to the same 
      # underlying object.
      my_dict2 = my_dict1
      my_dict3 = my_dict2
      ```

      Therefore, the following are *all* `True`:

      ```py
      # Each of these is True because the underlying object is the same
      # blob of memory.
      print(my_dict3 is my_dict2)    # True
      print(my_dict2 is my_dict1)    # True
      print(my_dict3 is my_dict1)    # True
      # And each of these is True because all variables have the same value.
      print(my_dict3 == my_dict2)    # True
      print(my_dict2 == my_dict1)    # True
      print(my_dict3 == my_dict1)    # True
      ```
   3. If you *independently assign* the same literal value to mutable types, however, each mutable variable points to *its own* underlying object in memory, since it is expected to be able to independently mutate the memory it points to:

      ```py
      # **Mutable type:** each variable has an **independent underlying 
      # object**, even though each of those underlying objects has the same
      # value.
      my_dict1 = {"key": "value"}
      my_dict2 = {"key": "value"}
      my_dict3 = {"key": "value"}
      # Therefore, each of these is False because the underlying objects 
      # differ.
      print(my_dict3 is my_dict2)    # False
      print(my_dict2 is my_dict1)    # False
      print(my_dict3 is my_dict1)    # False
      # But, each of these is True because all variables have the same value.
      print(my_dict3 == my_dict2)    # True
      print(my_dict2 == my_dict1)    # True
      print(my_dict3 == my_dict1)    # True
      ```
   4. If you pass a *mutable* variable to a function, and that function modifies it, the modification will automatically be seen outside the function. This is a *side effect*:

      ```py
      def modify_dict(my_dict):
          my_dict["new_key"] = "new_value"

      my_dict1 = {"key": "value"}
      modify_dict(my_dict1)
      print(my_dict1)  # prints: {"key": "value", "new_key": "new_value"}
      ```
   5. To force a *mutable* type to be passed *by value* instead of *by reference*, you can call the `.copy()` method to force a copy of the underlying object to be made.

      ```py
      my_dict1 = {"key": "value"}
      # Force-copy **by value**, so each variable has its own underlying 
      # object. The `.copy()` method makes an entirely new copy of the 
      # underlying object.
      my_dict2 = my_dict1.copy()
      my_dict3 = my_dict2.copy()
      # Therefore, each of these is False because the underlying objects 
      # differ.
      print(my_dict3 is my_dict2)    # False
      print(my_dict2 is my_dict1)    # False
      print(my_dict3 is my_dict1)    # False
      # But, each of these is True because all variables have the same value.
      print(my_dict3 == my_dict2)    # True
      print(my_dict2 == my_dict1)    # True
      print(my_dict3 == my_dict1)    # True
      ```
7. ***Immutable* types are passed *by copy*, and do *not* cause *side effects*.**

   1. If you do `my_int3 = my_int2 = my_int1 = 1`, then change `my_int3`, it does *not* change `my_int2` or `my_int1`, because that would be a side effect. It has no *side effects.*
   2. However, if you assign the same value to multiple immutable variables, whether by *chain assignment* *or* *independent literal assignment*, the variables are both equal (`var1 == var2` is `True`) *and* they are the same (`var1 is var2` is `True`), as shown here:

      ```py
      ## **Immutable types:** each variable apparently has the **same 
      # underlying object**, but side effects are not allowed
      my_int1 = 7
      my_int2 = 7
      my_int3 = 7
      # Therefore, each of these is True because the underlying objects are 
      # the same.
      print(my_int3 is my_int2)      # True
      print(my_int2 is my_int1)      # True
      print(my_int3 is my_int1)      # True
      # And, each of these is also True because all variables have the 
      # same value.
      print(my_int3 == my_int2)      # True
      print(my_int2 == my_int1)      # True
      print(my_int3 == my_int1)      # True

      # Try the test again, this time like this
      my_int1 = 7
      my_int2 = my_int1
      my_int3 = my_int2
      # Same as above: same underlying object, so each of these is True
      print(my_int3 is my_int2)      # True
      print(my_int2 is my_int1)      # True
      print(my_int3 is my_int1)      # True
      # Same as above: same value, so each of these is True
      print(my_int3 == my_int2)      # True
      print(my_int2 == my_int1)      # True
      print(my_int3 == my_int1)      # True
      print()
      ```

      That's a bit confusing, but the immutability and lack of side effects holds true.
   3. If you pass an *immutable* variable to a function, and that function modifies it, the modification will *not* be seen outside the function. There are no side effects. Rather, if you want to see the change outside the function, you must return the modified variable from the function, and reassign it outside the function.

      ```py
      def modify_int(my_int):
          my_int += 1
          return my_int

      my_int1 = 7
      # reassign the returned value to obtain the change from inside the
      # function
      my_int1 = modify_int(my_int1)  
      print(my_int1)  # prints: 8
      ```
   4. To force an *immutable* type to be passed *by reference* instead of *by copy*, you can simply wrap the immutable type inside of a mutable type, such as a list, and then pass the mutable wrapper to a function. This way, it gets passed by reference, and the side effect of modifying its contents is automatically visible outside the function:

      ```py
      def modify_immutable_type_hack(var_list):
          var_list[0] += 1  # increment the number inside the first element

      my_int = 10
      my_int_list = [my_int]
      print(my_int_list[0])  # 10
      # Force an immutable type to act mutable by passing it inside a list,
      # which is a mutable type, into a function. This way, the "side effect"
      # of the change to the list being visible outside the function is still
      # seen. This is because the list gets passed **by reference** instead
      # of **by value.**
      modify_immutable_type_hack(my_int_list)
      print(my_int_list[0])  # 11
      print(my_int)          # 10
      ```

      For single numbers, however, it's clearer to just use the return value method above, instead: `my_int1 = modify_int(my_int1)`.
8. You can write a program to automatically identify whether a type is *mutable* or *immutable* by looking for and identifying *side effects*. I do this below.
9. Python is *not* an easy programming language. It has tons of nuances like this. It's just popular, different, and very high level.

All of the test code for the above learning is below.

### 2. List of mutable vs immutable objects in Python

Here's a list of the most common mutable and immutable objects in Python. This list can be obtained by 1) painstakingly searching [Python's official "Built-in Types" reference page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html) for the words "mutable" and "immutable", *or* by 2) asking GitHub Copilot (or BingAI or ChatGPT) for it. I did both. The latter is, of course, way faster, but requires verification. I verified and updated the list below based on my own findings, and added all quotes, mostly from the official documentation.

**Mutable objects:**

- [list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#lists) - "Lists are mutable sequences"
- [set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) - "The set type is mutable"
- [dict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) - "A mapping object maps hashable values to arbitrary objects. Mappings are mutable objects. There is currently only one standard mapping type, the *dictionary*."
- [bytearray](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytearray)

  - "As bytearray objects are mutable, they support the mutable sequence operations in addition to the common bytes and bytearray operations"
  - "bytearray objects are mutable and have an efficient overallocation mechanism"
  - "bytearray objects are a mutable counterpart to bytes objects."

**Immutable objects:**

- All [numeric types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex). The official Python docs say nothing about their immutability, but every source and AI I find confirms they are immutable, as does my personal testing below. From [RealPython.com:](https://realpython.com/python-mutable-vs-immutable-types/#immutable-built-in-data-types-in-python) "Numeric types...are immutable."

  - int
  - float
  - complex
  - bool
- [str](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str) - "Strings are immutable sequences of Unicode code points."
- [bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes-objects) - "Bytes objects are immutable sequences of single bytes."
- [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuples) - "Tuples are immutable sequences, typically used to store collections of heterogeneous data"
- [frozenset](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) - "The frozenset type is immutable and hashable"
- [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#ranges) - "The range type represents an immutable sequence of numbers and is commonly used for looping a specific number of times in for loops."

---

**Stop here if you like. The above is the most important.**

---

### 3. Reassignment

All variables can be reassigned in Python, whether they were previously assigned to mutable or immutable types. However, the behavior of reassignment is different for mutable and immutable types, and cannot be thought of purely in traditional C and C++-like memory terms and understanding. Python is Python, and Python is different.

Coming from C and C++ as my primary languages, the concept of "mutability" in Python is quite confusing. For this and other reasons, I do *not* consider Python to be an "easy" or "beginner" language. It is simply a very powerful "extra high-level" language, is all. It has a *ton* of very nuanced and confusing points. C is more straight-forward and concrete in this regard. (And [C++ is just nuts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47002799/what-does-the-ampersand-at-the-end-of-member-function-signature-mean/47003980#comment109357350_47003980)).

In C and C++, my mental model of each variable is that it is a chunk of bytes in memory. When you do this:

```cpp
int var = 0;  // statically allocate bytes for `var`, and mutate them into a 0
var = 7;      // mutate the bits in `var` into a 7 now instead of a 0
```

...you are changing the bytes in `var`'s chunk of memory from bits storing a `0`, to bits storing a `7`. You have "mutated" the memory allocated by that variable, meaning: the chunk of memory which is set apart for it. The *type* of the variable simply specifies the *"lens"* (think: looking through a magic glass lens that interprets bits into numbers, letters, etc.), or *interpretation algorithm*, through which you will interpret those bits (ex: `float`, `int`, `char`, etc.).

In Python, however, that is *not* the mental model you should have for variables. **In Python, think of variables as *objects containing pointers to other objects*,** where *everything is an object*, and each object contains a bit specifying whether it is *mutable* or *immutable*, and *mutable* variables are passed *by reference* whereas *immutable* variables are *passed by value*. Note also that an object is a *very sophisticated dynamically-allocated instance of a class, which manages its own state and chunk of memory*, kind of like a [std container](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) in C++.

You can instantly see that types `int`, `bool`, `float`, etc. are all *classes* (objects) in Python, not just trivial types like they are in C and C++, by doing this:

```py
type(7)     # returns <class 'int'>
type(True)  # returns <class 'bool'>
type(1.0)   # returns <class 'float'>
```

So, in Python, when you do this:

```py
# dynamically allocate a pointer variable object named `var`, then
# dynamically allocate an integer object with a `0` in it, then point `var`
# to that int object which contains a `0`.
var = 0  # 0 is the value contained inside an immutable type `int` object

# dynamically allocate a new integer object with a `7` in it, then point `var`
# to that new, underlying int object which contains a `7`. Therefore,
# this simply re-assigns the variable `var` from pointing to the `0`
# object, to  pointing to the `7` object; the `int` object with a `0`
# in it is now "orphaned" and I suspect will be garbage collected, but that 
# level of understanding is beyond me.
var = 7
```

In the case of mutable objects, the reassignment modifies its bytes in-place rather than dynamically creating a new object and pointing the variable to it. For example:

```py
my_dict = {}  # dynamically allocate a pointer variable named `my_dict`,
              # dynamically allocate a dict object, then point `my_dict` to
              # that dict object
my_dict["some_key"] = "some_value"  # mutate the dict object by adding a
                                    # key-value pair
```

The details of how that "immutable" vs "mutable" characteristic is carried out aren't really important to the Python programmer like they would be to a low-level embedded systems C and C++ programmer like myself. Rather, it's sort of "hand-wavy". The Python programmer is supposed to just blindly accept it and move on. Some high-level C++ programmers are this way too. It's a mindset thing.

So, as long as you know the summary in section 1 above, and the list of mutable vs immutable objects in Python in section 2 above, you are good.

### 4. Pass *by reference* vs pass *by copy*, and *side effects*

What a good Python programmer *does* need to know, however, is whether or not their particular variable type will be passed *by reference* or *by copy* when passed to a function. This is a very important distinction, as passing *by reference* causes *side effects*, which means that changes to the variable in one place will result to changes to that or other variables in other places, such as inside vs outside a function. This is a very important concept in Python, and to me is the main reason why the distinction between mutable and immutable types is important. I don't really care how they work under the hood otherwise.

Again:

1. Passing a **mutable** type to a function causes *side effects*, which means modifications to that variable inside the function *will* be seen outside the function.
2. Passing an **immutable** type to a function does not cause side effects, which means modifications to that variable inside the function will *not* be seen outside the function.

### 5. `is` vs `==`

The operator `==` tests for equality of values stored within a variable. The operator `is`, I think, is used to test if two variables refer to the same object in memory. Again, the nuances of how Python does this under-the-hood are beyond me. See my section 1 summary, however, for a bunch of nuanced cases of `is` vs `==`.

The official Python documentation describes the `is` and `is not` operators under the "Identity comparisons" section of its documentation here: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#is-not:

> The operators `is` and `is not` test for an object’s identity: `x is y` is true if and only if `x` and `y` are the same object. An Object’s identity is determined using the `id()` function. `x is not y` yields the inverse truth value.

The `id()` function says: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id:

> Return the “identity” of an object. This is an integer which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object during its lifetime. Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same `id()` value.

So, I interpret this to mean that the `id()` is a unique dynamic memory address, or index into a map to one, which is assigned to each object at object creation. When you do `my_int3 = my_int2 = my_int1 = 7`, the `id()` of all 4 of those parts is the same:

```py
my_int3 = my_int2 = my_int1 = 7
print(id(my_int1))  # 140201501393328
print(id(my_int2))  # 140201501393328
print(id(my_int3))  # 140201501393328
print(id(7))        # 140201501393328
```

So, they all appear to be the same underlying object, or blob of memory.

### 6. Some test code

Here's my test code. Nearly all of the behaviors in my test code were unpredictable to me, since Python is such a dramatically different language from C and C++, and I was unable guess the results of most of these tests prior to running them and doing this learning. I had just about everything wrong.

[**mutable_vs_immutable_types.py**](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/python/mutable_vs_immutable_types.py) from my [eRCaGuy_hello_world](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/) repo.

Note: the test code is too long to paste in this answer, as the Stack Overflow limit is 30000 chars. So, see it at the link above.

**Sample run and output:**

```
eRCaGuy_hello_world$ python/mutable_vs_immutable_types.py 
var before modification: True
var is a bool
var after modification:  False

var before modification: 1.0
var is a float
var after modification:  2.0

var before modification: 7
var is an int
var after modification:  8

var before modification: some words
var is a str (string)
var after modification:  some words; some more words

var before modification: [7, 8, 9]
var is a list
var after modification:  [7, 8, 9, 1]

var before modification: {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
var is a dict
var after modification:  {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'new_key': 'new_value'}

var before modification: (7, 8, 9)
var is a tuple
var after modification:  (1, 2, 3)

is_mutable(my_bool, True)                                    -->  immutable
is_mutable(my_float, 1.0)                                    -->  immutable
is_mutable(my_int, 7)                                        -->  immutable
is_mutable(my_str, "some words")                             -->  immutable
is_mutable(my_list, [7, 8, 9])                               -->  mutable
is_mutable(my_dict, {"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"})    -->  mutable
is_mutable(my_tuple, (7, 8, 9))                              -->  immutable

int is immutable
list is mutable

MUTABLE TYPES
False
False
False
True
True
True

IMMUTABLE TYPES
True
True
True
True
True
True

integer types again
True
True
True
True
True
True

True
True
True
True
True
True

False
False
False
True
True
True

How to update immutable vs mutable variables in a function:

7
8

[7, 8, 9]
[7, 8, 9, 1]

10
11
10
```

### References

1. Nearly all of the references are my links and test code above.
2. This is my own work, but for anyone curious, here's in introductory conversation I had with GitHub Copilot to get me started:

Comment: This is utter nonsense.  All object types are passed and assigned in exactly the same way; the difference is that mutable types have defined operations that change their internal state, and immutable types don't.

Comment: @jasonharper, I'm sure if I edit my utter nonsense in just the right way I can make it correct then, because the test code does work our correctly, and I did find the bulk of the official references for which types are mutable vs immutable. It's hard to make sense of all of this but clearly I'm willing to try.

Comment: @jasonharper, if you can tell me which parts are utter nonsense and provide some links or info. on how I can verify it, I will edit or remove them.

Comment: Your two most fundamental misunderstandings seem to be these: 1) variables are *not* objects, they're just a name for an object; 2) `var = new` and `var[idx] = new` are fundamentally different operations, even though we call both of them "assignment".  The former changes what object the variable refers to, with the previous value (if any) playing no part.  The latter doesn't affect the variable at all, it just requests the referred-to object to perform an internal modification (which only mutable objects will implement).

Comment: @jasonharper, I see your points. I'll see if I can fix up this answer this weekend. I think if I can straighten things out and present the test code correctly with the logic and reasoning factually correct, this answer will contribute value. The test code works, but my reasoning for why it works is botched it seems. That's why I'm here. To learn.

Answer (score -2):

In Python, there's a easy way to know:

Immutable:

```
    >>> s='asd'
    >>> s is 'asd'
    True
    >>> s=None
    >>> s is None
    True
    >>> s=123
    >>> s is 123
    True
```

Mutable:

```
>>> s={}
>>> s is {}
False
>>> {} is {}
Flase
>>> s=[1,2]
>>> s is [1,2]
False
>>> s=(1,2)
>>> s is (1,2)
False
```

And:

```
>>> s=abs
>>> s is abs
True
```

So I think built-in function is also immutable in Python.

But I really don't understand how float works:

```
>>> s=12.3
>>> s is 12.3
False
>>> 12.3 is 12.3
True
>>> s == 12.3
True
>>> id(12.3)
140241478380112
>>> id(s)
140241478380256
>>> s=12.3
>>> id(s)
140241478380112
>>> id(12.3)
140241478380256
>>> id(12.3)
140241478380256
```

It's so weird.

Comment: But that is clearly not valid. Because tuples are immutable. Type `x = (1, 2)` and then try and mutate `x`, it's not possible. One way I have found to check for mutability is `hash`, it works for the builtin objects at least. `hash(1)` `hash('a')` `hash((1, 2))` `hash(True)` all work, and `hash([])` `hash({})` `hash({1, 2})` all do not work.

Comment: @semicolon For user-defined classes then `hash()` will work if the object defines a `__hash__()` method, even though user-defined classes are generally mutable.

Comment: @augurar I mean yes, but nothing in Python will guarantee anything, because Python has no real static typing or formal guarantees. But the `hash` method is still a pretty good one, because mutable objects should generally not have a `__hash__()` method, since making them keys in a dictionary is just dangerous.

Comment: @augurar and semicolon (or others if they know it): __hash__() solution ... does creator of a custom class have to add it for it to be there?  If so, then the rule is if exists the object should be immutable; if it does not exist, we can't tell since creator may have simply left if off.

Answer (score -2):

For immutable objects, assignment creates a new copy of values, for example.

```
x=7
y=x
print(x,y)
x=10 # so for immutable objects this creates a new copy so that it doesnot 
#effect the value of y
print(x,y)
```

For mutable objects, the assignment doesn't create another copy of values. For example,

```
x=[1,2,3,4]
print(x)
y=x #for immutable objects assignment doesn't create new copy 
x[2]=5
print(x,y) # both x&y holds the same list
```

Comment: Absolutely incorrect. Assignment **never creates a copy**. Please read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html  In the first case, `x=10` is simply *another assignment*, while `x[2] = 5` calls a mutator method. `int` objects *simply lack mutator methods*, but the semantics of python assignment **do not depend on the type**