# How do I make Python make all identical strings use the same memory?

Tags: python, memory-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does python *intern* do, and when should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136826/what-does-python-intern-do-and-when-should-it-be-used)

I am working with a program in python that has to correlate on an array with millions of string objects. I've discovered that if they all come from the same quoted string, each additional "string" is just a reference to the first, master string. However if the strings are read from a file, and if the strings are all equal, each one still requires new memory allocation.

That is, this takes about 14meg of storage:

```
a = ["foo" for a in range(0,1000000)]
```

While this requires more than 65meg of storage:

```
a = ["foo".replace("o","1") for a in range(0,1000000)]
```

Now I can make the memory take much less space with this:

```
s = {"f11":"f11"}
a = [s["foo".replace("o","1")] for a in range(0,1000000)]
```

But that seems silly. Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: @Maulwurfn, just because the answer is the same doesn't mean the question is the same.

Comment: why don't you store the value of `replace` operation first?

Comment: How are you measuring the size of the lists? If I use `sys.getsizeof(["foo" for a in range(0,1000000)])` I get the same size as `sys.getsizeof(["foo".replace("o","1") for a in range(0,1000000)])` -- at least in Python 3.2

Comment: @JBernardo, I did not store the value of the `replace` operation first because I was intentionally trying to generate *new* strings, rather than lots of references to an old string.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

just do an `intern()`, which tells Python to store and take the string from memory:

```
a = [intern("foo".replace("o","1")) for a in range(0,1000000)]
```

This also results around 18MB, same as in the first example.

Also note the comment below, if you use python3. Thx @Abe Karplus

Comment: Note that in Python 3, `intern` has been renamed `sys.intern`.

Comment: +1 I didn't knew about `intern()`.

Comment: Thanks great. Thanks. I didn't know about intern. Yes, I'm using Python3, so I'll need to use sys.intern().

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this:

```
strs=["this is string1","this is string2","this is string1","this is string2",
      "this is string3","this is string4","this is string5","this is string1",
      "this is string5"]
new_strs=[]
for x in strs:
    if x in new_strs:
        new_strs.append(new_strs[new_strs.index(x)]) #find the index of the string
                                                     #and instead of appending the
                                                #string itself, append it's reference.
    else:
        new_strs.append(x)

print [id(y) for y in new_strs]
```

strings which are identical will now have the same `id()`

**output:**

```
[18632400, 18632160, 18632400, 18632160, 18651400, 18651440, 18651360, 18632400, 18651360]
```

Comment: Nice idea. Unfortunately it's an O(n**2) algorithm which will get really slow as the list gets longer.

Answer (score -1):

Keeping a dictionary of seen strings should work

```
new_strs = []
str_record = {}
for x in strs:
    if x not in str_record:
        str_record[x] = x
    new_strs.append(str_record[x])
```

(Untested.)