# String assignment

Tags: python

I have a look at python code where string variable assignments looks like:

```
var1 = var2[:]
```

I am just wondering what is the difference between:

```
var1 = var2
```

Here is my experiments:

```
>>> original = "some text"
>>> copy1 = original
>>> copy2 = original[:]
>>> original = "another text"
>>> copy1
'some text'
>>> copy2
'some text'
```

**Updated:**

Here is a full [code](http://pastebin.com/CvTgkPz9).  This code search a key for substitution cipher.
If I remove '[:]' this code will works very slowly.

Comment: Do you want to know what `[:]` means or do you want to know why it doesn't seem to make a difference here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Due to [interning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136826/what-does-python-intern-do-and-when-should-it-be-used), there is often no difference (in the resulting object) between the two. We may check whether two variables point to the same object by using the `is` operator, which in contrast to the `==` operator checks wheter the actual memory address of the objects are the same:

```
>>> a = "foo"
>>> b = a
>>> a is b
True
>>> c = a[:]
>>> a is c
True
```

Interning is a mechanism for saving memory and speeding up comparisons of immutable objects, and it works like this: before creating a new immutable, python checks to see if an identical immutable already exists. If so, it just uses a reference to the existing object. It can do that without harm because there's no way to change an immutable. This is why even two independently created strings may point to the same object:

```
>>> a = "foo"
>>> b = "foo"
>>> a is b
True
```

But if `var2` was some mutable sequential object, like a `list`, then `var2[:]` would be a shallow copy of `var2`, so that making changes to one would not affect the other.

```
>>> a = list("foo")
>>> a
['f', 'o', 'o']
>>> b = a
>>> b is a
True
>>> c = a[:]
>>> c is a
False
>>> b.pop()
'o'
>>> a
['f', 'o']
>>> b
['f', 'o']
>>> c
['f', 'o', 'o']
```

For the full picture, also read Ashwini Chaudharys answer.

Answer (score 2):

`[:]`  notation is used for slicing,

`a[m:n]` will return characters starting from index `m` upto `n-1`, if nothing is passed it returns the whole string back.

```
In [1]: a="foobar"

In [2]: a[:]          #this is equal to a only as nothing to passed to slicing
Out[2]: 'foobar'

In [3]: a[1:]         #return everything after index 1
Out[3]: 'oobar'

In [4]: a[:1]         #return everything before 1st index
Out[4]: 'f'

In [5]: a[:-1]        #return everything before the last character
Out[5]: 'fooba'
```

DIFFERENCE between `b=a[:]` and `b=a` is that b=a takes less number of steps internally:

```
In [7]: def func1():
   ...:     a="foo"
   ...:     b=a
   ...:     

In [8]: def func2():
   ...:     a="foo"
   ...:     b=a[:]
   ...:     

In [9]: dis.dis(func1)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('foo')
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (a)

  3           6 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              9 STORE_FAST               1 (b)
             12 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             15 RETURN_VALUE        

In [10]: dis.dis(func2)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('foo')
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (a)

  3           6 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              9 SLICE+0             
             10 STORE_FAST               1 (b)
             13 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             16 RETURN_VALUE
```

`timeit`:

```
In [11]: %timeit func1()
1000000 loops, best of 3: 336 ns per loop

In [12]: %timeit func2()
1000000 loops, best of 3: 397 ns per loop
```

Comment: I know about slicing, but I don't know why there is difference between   var1 and var1[:]

Comment: @demas `var1[:]` takes larger number of steps internally.

Answer (score 1):

In the full code you link to, there is a possibility of `original` being a `list`, not a `str`:

```
parentkey,parentscore = startkey or list('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'),-99e99
```

and then

```
child = parentkey[:]
# swap two characters in the child
child[a],child[b] = child[b],child[a]
```

As mentioned by **lazyr**, creating a copy will make a difference in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Note that in your code, the variable can be a `list` rather than a string.

See the following example:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = a
>>> b[0] = 'foo'
>>> a
['foo', 2, 3]
```

But:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = a[:]
>>> b[0] = 'foo'
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
```

In other words, in the first example, the reference to `a` is preserved in `b` and changing `b` changes `a`. Using the slice notation `[:]` makes a deep (1 level) copy instead.

Comment: You just got the last sentence the wrong way round: `[:]` makes a **deep** copy (well, one extra layer deep). It is a really handy way to copy, say, a list of strings.

Answer (score 0):

`a[:]` is the same as just `a`, `id(a) == id(a[:])`, so there is no difference)

```
a = 'Convert an integer number to a binary string Convert an integer number to a binary'
id(a) == id(a[:])
>>> True
```

For list [:] returns a copy of it.

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
id(a) == id(a[:])
>>> False
```