# Python 3.3, Global responds to one string but not to another

Tags: python, string, global

When I run this code, it responds with UnboundLocalError: local variable 'hhh' referenced before assignment. However, the global string 'temp' does not respond with such an error despite being defined in a similar manner. Any help would be fantastic, thank you.

```
    import random, os
def start():
    global level
    global hhh
    global temp
    level=1
    temp='     +-!'
    hhh='[X'
    os.system('CLS')
    actualcrawl()
def actualcrawl():
    print (temp)
    for a in range(2,128):
        hhh=hhh+temp[random.randrange(1,8)]
    hhh=hhh[:79]+'>'+hhh[80:]
    for i in range(1,3):
        a=random.randrange(3,8)
        b=random.randrange(6,15)
        hhh=hhh[:16*a+b-1]+'='+hhh[16*a+b:]
    for i in range(1,9):
        print (hhh[16*i-16:16*i])
```

Comment: where are these global variables defined?

Comment: you don't assign to `temp` in `actualcrawl` but you do assign to `hhh`

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,you should take a look at this question [Using global variables in a function other than the one that created them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them)

Briefly speaking,if it is only reading from a name, and the name doesn't exist locally, it will try to look up the name in any containing scopes.That's what happens to `temp`,which will be found in the global scope.But with `hhh`,you do writing,which will make Python believe that `hhh` is a local variable.

And another thing,but more important,it is not recomended using `global`.You could invoke `actualcrawl()` in `start()`,and pass in `hhh,temp`,which is the way most people do.

EDIT

It is simple:

```
import random,os
def start():
    level=1
    temp='     +-!'
    hhh='[X'
    os.system('CLS')
    actualcrawl(temp,hhh)

def actualcrawl(temp,hhh):
    print (temp)
    for a in range(2,128):
        hhh=hhh+temp[random.randrange(1,8)]
    hhh=hhh[:79]+'>'+hhh[80:]
    for i in range(1,3):
        a=random.randrange(3,8)
        b=random.randrange(6,15)
        hhh=hhh[:16*a+b-1]+'='+hhh[16*a+b:]
    for i in range(1,9):
        print (hhh[16*i-16:16*i])
```

I don't know what language you use before Python,but you really don't need to declare a variable like in C/C++.Because when you assign to a variable, you are just binding the name to an object.See this [python variables are pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13530998/python-variables-are-pointers)

Comment: I have been programming in python for 2 days now and have no idea how to pass variables. How would one go about doing something like that?

Comment: Nevermind, thank you very much. Passing variables works beautifully.