# Proper cross validation and matrix processing in python

Tags: python, matrix

I am trying to perform in python, cross-validation. My databaset have size 31x9. I want to split the matrix into matrixes with size 28 and 3 for the evaluation. Moreover in the test matrix I want to replace the last two columns equal to zero. My code is the following:

```
def printme(training):
    train_list = []
    test_list = []
    num_folds = 10
    subset_size = len(training)/num_folds
    for i in range(num_folds):
            testing_this_round = training[i*subset_size:][:subset_size]
            training_this_round = training[:i*subset_size] + training[(i+1)*subset_size:]
            train_list.append(training_this_round)
            new_test = testing_this_round

            new_test[0][8] = 0
            new_test[1][8] = 0
            new_test[2][8] = 0

            new_test[0][7] = 0
            new_test[1][7] = 0
            new_test[2][7] = 0

            test_list.append(new_test)

    return train_list, test_list
```

The crossvalidation seems to work fine, however when I am trying to make the last two columsn of test matrix equal to zero, I entounted problems. It seems that my code affect also the training matrix. How can I overcome this problem? In the returned matrices train_list and test_list in both of them the last two columns was changed to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is importing `copy` and use its `deepcopy` function. Then you would just have to replace

```
testing_this_round = training[i*subset_size:][:subset_size]
```

by

```
testing_this_round = copy.deepcopy(training[i*subset_size:][:subset_size])
```

Actually your code was not affecting "also" the training list, since it was the same matrix, but with two different names. For more details, see *e.g.* [python variables are pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13530998/python-variables-are-pointers)