# Simple python leetCode not accepted on technicality?

Tags: python

I have a very simple algorithm question [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-duplicates-from-sorted-array/description/), which asks to remove duplicates from a list and return the length of the new list.

Here's my code in `py3`:

```
class Solution:
    def removeDuplicates(self, nums):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :rtype: int
        """
        nums = list(set(nums))
        return len(nums)
```

This works fine when I test it in my terminal. But according to leetCode, input: `[1,1,2]` puts out `[1,1]` instead of `[1,2]`. Assuming leetCode doesn't have a bug, I can only come to the conclusion that there's something going on with the scope of `nums`? Maybe `nums` is being treated like a local variable when set using `nums = list(set(nums))`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python variables are pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13530998/python-variables-are-pointers)

Comment: The question on the site you linked to explicitly says: "Given a sorted array, remove the duplicates **in-place** such that each element appear only once and return the new length.

**Do not allocate extra space for another array, you must do this by modifying the input array in-place with O(1) extra memory.**"  (emphasis mine).  That's not what you're doing - you're allocating a set, leaving the initial list exactly as it was, and creating a new list based off of the set, and returning that.  You're using O(n) of memory, not O(1).

Comment: I might be missing something, but the _nums_ value given is a tuple which is immutable. How are you supposed to change it in place without creating a new sequence object?

Comment: @dfundako, I really doubt the input is immutable, since they tell you that you are given an array (that's a list in python)

Comment: @jtagle nums = [1,1,2],     if that comma is part of the array, it is a tuple when you return _type_

Comment: @dfundako: The annotations in the comments clearly show the `nums` parameter is a `list`.

Comment: I just tested the code some more and it seems like the list is immutable if I set it with `nums = list(set(nums))`, that is `nums` doesn't change after the function at all. But modifying `nums` via individual elements does. Really kind of weird.

Comment: @thestateofmay, it's not wierd, that's how it is supposed to work with python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test code now on the web you linked. But I think you can imagine the testcase as follow (I'm just guessing here, so this answer might not work properly):

```
class Solution:
    def removeDuplicates(self, nums):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :rtype: int
        """
        nums = list(set(nums))
        return len(nums)

nums = [1, 1, 2]
solver = Solution()
length = solver.removeDuplicates(nums)
print(nums[:length])
```

So, by watching the test case, you can see that you actually get `[1, 1]`, since you are not modifying the list, but you are creating a new local variable within the method scope. You could try doing something like this maybe:

```
class Solution:
    def removeDuplicates(self, nums):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :rtype: int
        """
        i = 0
        while i < len(nums) - 1:
            if nums[i] == nums[i+1]:
                del nums[i]
            else:
                i += 1
        return len(nums)

nums = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3]
solver = Solution()

length = solver.removeDuplicates(nums)
print(nums[:length])
```

When they ask for an algorithm "in-place" you are not supposed to create new variables (or overwritte the old one with a new list), that's not O(1) extra memory, it's O(n), since you are creating a new copy.

**EDIT** A bit more explanation

What is happening with your code, is that you create a new local variable in a new memory space (In case you know about computers, you create it in the stack) therefore, inside your function you lose the reference to the pointer that gives you the outter nums variable (the original list). So the nums variable in the function (stack) is setted as a list created by iterating all different elements of the original list. Then, you really get a copy that meet all the requirements and is stored in the stack, but the old list stays the same. Then, when you exit your function, the stack variable is lost, so when you access to the `num` variable, you will get the old one (the original).

To understand what's going on here, you can read [this](https://www.python-course.eu/global_vs_local_variables.php) to learn about scopes, and [this](https://www.python-course.eu/passing_arguments.php) to learn about passing arguments to functions.

Comment: hmm it seems if I create a new variable and set `nums` equal to it `nums` doesn't change at all. Which seems kind of weird since manipulating individual elements within `nums` like the way you described it changes `nums`

Comment: Give me a sec, I'll try to explain better on the answer to see. ¿Have you coded in C or more low level languages?

Comment: so even though `nums` is the same name as the argument, `nums = list(set(nums))` is actually creating a new local variable? then how can one write a `void` function that modifies the given inputs?

Comment: Indeed, you are creating a new variable. Being a void function doesn't mean you can't change variables inside them. You can create a void function that recieves an array, modify it and then the function doesn't return.