# Given a sorted array, remove the duplicates in-place such that each element appear only once and return the new length

Tags: python, list

The full question, and I'm starting to learn python online but having issue with this question marked as easy

> Given a sorted array, remove the duplicates in-place such that each
>   element appear only once and return the new length. Do not allocate
>   extra space for another array, you must do this by modifying the input
>   array in-place with O(1) extra memory.

```
class Solution(object):
    def removeDuplicates(self, nums):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :rtype: int
        """
        k=0
        for i in range(i+1,len(nums)-1):
            j=i+1

            for j in range(j+1,len(len(nums))):
                if nums[i] == nums[j]:
                    del nums[j]
        len_list = nums
        return(len_list, nums)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.  You haven't asked a question.

Comment: Oh I shared my code but it's wrong, I just wanna know how it's wrong and I shared the question too at first.

Comment: can you kindly add a full answer so I can test then accept it if it works for me, thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple python leetCode not accepted on technicality?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49071897/simple-python-leetcode-not-accepted-on-technicality)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is fairly easy, once you realize you have to work from the *end* of the list, so that your deletions do not change the part of the list you have not yet examined.

```
a = [1,1,1,3,4,5,5,5,5,7,7,7,9,9]
for i in range(len(a)-1,0,-1):
    if a[i] == a[i-1]:
        del a[i]
```

Result is

```
[1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9]
```

Answer (score 1):

First answer from @BoarGules is the best one. But we can do it in forward direction also.

```
a = [1,1,1,3,4,5,5,5,5,7,7,7,9,9]
i =0
l = len(a)-1
while i < l :
    if a[i] == a[i+1]:
        del a[i+1]
        l -=1
    else :
        i +=1    
print(a)
```

Result will be :

```
[1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are solving a LeetCode question:
https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-duplicates-from-sorted-array/

If yes, this should be your answer:

```
class Solution:
    def removeDuplicates(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        if len(nums) == 1:
            return 1

        i = 0
        for j in range(1, len(nums)):
            if (nums[i] != nums[j]):
                i += 1
                nums[i] = nums[j]

        return i + 1
```

> It doesn't matter what you leave beyond the returned length.

Answer (score 0):

below code remove duplicates & sort array in descending order.

```
class Solution(object):
    def thirdMax(self, nums):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :rtype: int
        """
        a_value=sorted(set(nums),reverse=True)
        if len(a_value) > 2:
           a=a_value[2]
        else:
           a=a_value[0]
        return a
```