# python modifies variable that is used as an argument of a function. How to prevent it properly?

Tags: python, numpy, scientific-computing

If a variable is used as an argument of a function, then all modifications done inside the function with the argument apply to the variable. [This is normal and expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13530998/python-variables-are-pointers), but in many cases undesirable. What is the best practice to prevent this behaviour? Example:

```
import numpy as np
def func(A):
    for ind in range(A.shape[0]):  
        A[ind] = A[ind]+1
    return A

A = np.array([1, 2, 3])
NewA = func(A)
print(A)
print(NewA)
```

---

```
Out: [2, 3, 4]
Out: [2, 3, 4]
```

While we want:

```
Out: [1, 2, 3]
Out: [2, 3, 4]
```

So far I came up only with two ideas.

**Method one:** obviously, pass a copy of a variable:

```
A = np.array([1, 2, 3])
NewA = func(A.copy())
print(A)
print(NewA)
Out: [1, 2, 3]
Out: [2, 3, 4]
```

Returns what expected but becomes really annoying when one have a function of 5 arguments: it is just too long to type .copy() every time.

**Method two:**
Modify the function body

```
def func(A):
    B = A.copy()
    for ind in range(B.shape[0]):  
        B[ind] = B[ind]+1
    return B
```

This is equally annoying and requires modification of functions.
Any other ideas?

Comment: This shouldn't be surprising. Please read [this excellent blog post on python variables and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html). The key point you seem to be missing is you *are creating a new variable with function arguments*, but that new variable refers to the *same object*. So, *variables* aren't modified, objects are.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the responses. I've modified the question to highlight the difference between the proposed answer.

Answer (score -2):

This is due to the type of the parameter. If the parameter is an immutable object such as an `int` or a `string`, it acts like call by value. If it is a mutatable object such as `np.darray`, it acts like call by reference.

Comment: Absolutely incorrect. The evaluation strategy is always the same for Python, regardless of the object's type. Note, both `int` and `str` **are objects**. Everything in Python is an object.

Comment: Again, mutable and immutable objects **have the same evaluation strategy**, which is *neither* call by value nor call by reference. You simply cannot mutate immutable objects, so you cannot ever see any changes to them.