# Python attribute that holds other existing attributes in a list

Tags: python, list, oop

I am currently working on a python-sqlite project, and i am novice to both.

I have created a class that has some attributes declared inside the `__init__` method. I need another attribute that will be a list or array, that will contain some of the already declared attributes of the class. What i want is my list to contain just a reference of the original attributes.

I need this structure in order to be able to call these attributes together, to iterate on them, but i want to be able to call them separately, too.

At first I tried to create that list attribute inside the `__init__` method, after the rest declarations. When I create an instance, however, and change the initial value of one of the attributes, the attribute in the list is not updated.

Then I tried to create that same list attribute inside another method of the class, instead of inside the **init**, and call it from inside my code, and it did what I wanted to.

Why does the different approach has different results?

Here is the code at both cases:

**Case #1**

```
class Tools():
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "defaultname"
        self.manufacturer = "defaultmanuf"
        self.tooldetails = [self.name, self.manufacturer]

    def get_details(self):
        return self.tooldetails
```

**Case #2**

```
class Tools():
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "defaultname"
        self.manufacturer = "defaultmanuf"

    def _set_detail_list(self):
        self.tooldetails = [self.name, self.manufacturer]

    def get_details(self):
        _set_detail_list()
        return self.tooldetails
```

And when I create an instance:

```
tool1 = Tools()
tool1.name = 'abc'
tool1.get_details()
```

The first case gives me `["defaultname", "defaultmanuf"]` while the second gives me `["abc","defaultmanuf"]`.

My question is what is the reason python gives me different output for each case? It seems like I miss something important about how initialization is working..

`dir()` and other similar functions or magic methods could be able to give me what i want, but i think they are not flexible enough if you want many different lists with different sets of attributes. Unluckily, introspection doesn't work very well with sqlite string-formatted commands..

Plus i am curious of the way python works, which I believe is very important..

Thanks!!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question seems unclear. Can you please provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Try calling `dir()` on an instance of your class, e.g. `dir(some_object)`. Does that help?

Comment: @jpp it is my pleasure to be a member of your community. I added some code example. Maybe that helps? Thank you.

Comment: @Chris i need something fully customizable! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Case #1**

When your list is created within `__init__`, it contains pointers to 2 strings. But the link between `name` and `tooldetails` is irrevocably broken once your list is created. If you update `name`, `tooldetails` will not dynamically update, unless you tell Python to explicitly update `tooldetails` with new data.

**Case #2**

Here you *explicitly* tell Python to reconstruct `tooldetails` via the method `_set_detail_list`, which is called within `get_details`. You update `name` and *then* tell Python to rebuild the `tooldetails` list. Therefore, if you update `name` followed by `get_details`, your list will be updated.

Comment: that sounds perfectly logical, thank you very much!! I also did some extra digging [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13531072/9855924) . I guess that if these values (strings) were of some mutable type (eg lists) the first case would  work too?