# If two variables point to the same object, why doesn't reassigning one variable affect the other?

Tags: python, variables, reference, variable-assignment

I am trying to understand how variables work in python. Say I have an object stored in the variable `a`:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
```

If I assign `a` to `b`, both point to the same object:

```
>>> b = a
>>> b is a
True
```

But if I reassign `a` or `b`, that's no longer true:

```
>>> a = {'x': 'y'}
>>> a is b
False
```

The two variables now have different values:

```
>>> a
{'x': 'y'}
>>> b
[1, 2, 3]
```

I don't understand why the variables are different now. Why is `a is b` no longer true? Can someone explain what's going on?

Comment: Different variables may *point to* the same memory location, but that does not mean they *are* the same memory location. On reassignment, you change what that variable *points to*.

Comment: I went at your question with a chainsaw; let me know if I unintentionally changed what you were asking.

Comment: Unfortunately we can't use it as a dupe target but you have to read [this](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Comment: "why doesn't reassigning one variable affect the other?" For the **same reason** that, *when you made the second variable refer to the same object as the first*, that also didn't affect whatever the second variable might have been referring to *before* (and didn't raise an exception, if it didn't refer to anything).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Python has *names* which refer to *objects*. Objects exist separately from names, and names exist separately from the objects they refer to.

```
# name a
a = 1337
    # object 1337
```

When assigning "a name to a name", the right-hand side is *evaluated* to the referred to object. Similar to how `2 + 2` evaluates to `4`, `a` evaluates to the original `1337`.

```
# name b
b = a
    # object referred to by a -> 1337
```

At this point, we have `a -> 1337` and `b -> 1337` - note that neither name knows the other! If we test `a is b`, both names are *evaluated* to the same object which is obviously equal.

Reassigning a name only changes what that name refers to - there is no connection by which other names could be changed as well.

```
# name a - reassign
a = 9001
  # object 9001
```

At this point, we have `a -> 9001` and `b -> 1337`. If we now test `a is b`, both names are *evaluated* to different objects which are not the same.

---

If you come from languages such as C, then you are used to variables *containing* values. For example, `char a = 12` can be read as "`a` is a memory region containing `12`". On top, you can have several variables use the same memory. Assigning another value to a variable changes the content of the shared memory - and therefore the value of both variables.

```
+- char a -+
|       12 |
+--char b -+

# a = -128

+- char a -+
|     -128 |
+--char b -+
```

This is not how Python works: names do not contain anything, but refer to separate values. For example, `a = 12` can be read as "`a` is a name which refers to the value `12`". On top, you can have several names refer to the same value - but it will still be separate names, each with its own reference. Assigning another value to a name changes the reference of that name - but leaves the reference of the other name untouched.

```
+- name a -+ -\
               \
                --> +- <12> ---+
               /    |       12 |
+- name b -+ -/     +----------+

# a = -128
                    +- <-128> -+
+- name a -+ -----> |     -128 |
                    +----------+

                    +- <12> ---+
+- name b -+ -----> |       12 |
                    +----------+
```

---

A point of confusion is that *mutable* objects can appear to violate the separation of names and objects. Commonly, these are containers (e.g `list`, `dict`, ...) and classes exhibit the same behaviour by default.

```
# name m
m = [1337]
    # object [1337]
# name n
n = m
    # object referred to by m
```

Similar to a plain integer `1337`, a list containing an integer `[1337]` is *an object* that can be referred to by several, independent names. As above, `n is m` evaluates to `True` and `m = [9001]` does not change `n`.

However, certain operations on a name change the value seen by the name *and all aliases*.

```
# inplace add to m
m += [9001]
```

After this operation, `m == [1337, 9001]` *and* `n is m` still holds true. In fact, the value seen by `n` has also changed to `[1337, 9001]`. This appears to violate above behaviour, in which aliases did not influence each other.

This is because `m += [9001]` did not change what `m` refers to. It only change the *content* of the list that `m` (and the alias `n`) referred to. Both `m` and `n` still refer to the original list object, whose *value* was changed.

```
+- name m -+ -\
               \                  
                --> +- […] -+     +--- <@0> -+
               /    |    @0 |  -> |     1337 |
+- name n -+ -/     +-------+     +----------+

# m += [9001]

+- name m -+ -\
               \                  
                --> +- […] -+     +--- <@0> -++--- <@1> -+
               /    | @0 @1 |  -> |     1337 ||     9001 |
+- name n -+ -/     +-------+     +----------++----------+
```

Comment: If I have encountered this answers sooner it would have saved me from 2 days of frustrating debugging! Thank you for clearing this topic up in an easy-to-understand, clear manner!

Answer (score 4):

In Python, all variables are stored in dictionaries, or structures which seem a lot like dictionaries (e.g. `locals()` can expose the current scope/namespace as a dictionary).

**Note**: `PyObject*` is a CPython concept. I am not sure how things work in other Python implementations.

So it is flawed to view Python variables like C's where they have precise memory locations. Their **values** are `PyObject*` (pointers, or memory locations), not the actual primitive values. Since variables themselves are just entries in a dictionary which point to `PyObject*` pointers, changing the value of variable is actually giving it a different memory address to point to.

In CPython, it is these `PyObject*` values which are used by `id` and `is` (`a is b` is the same as `id(a) == id(b)`.)

For example, let's consider the simple line of code:

```
# x: int
x += 1
```

Actually changes the memory location associated with the variable. This is because it follows the following logic:

```
LOAD_FAST (x)
LOAD_CONST (1)
INPLACE_ADD
STORE_FAST (x)
```

Which is the bytecode which roughly says:

1. Lookup the value of x. Which is a (in CPython) `PyObject*` which points to `PyLongLong` or such (an `int` from the Python userland)
2. Load a value from a constant memory address
3. Add the two values. This will result in a new `PyObject*` which is also an `int`
4. Set the value associated with `x` to be this new pointer

**TL;DR**: everything, including primitives, in Python is an object. Variables don't store values per se, but instead the pointers which box them. Reassigning a variable changes the pointer associated with that name, not update the memory held in that location.

Comment: Nice insight into CPython, but I think it'd have been better to answer the question without digging into a specific implementation's internals. I don't think this is easy to understand for beginners.

Comment: I'm sure your answer will be helpful to people coming to Python from C, or who are otherwise familiar with pointers, but that doesn't seem to apply to the OP.

Comment: Good explanation for getting into Cpython. and pointers in memory location. But I guess, `variables are assigned to values and do not copy the value`..is precise response for this thread from https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html

Answer (score 4):

"*Say I have an object stored in the variable a*" - that is where you are going wrong.

Python objects are not stored *in* variables, they are *referred to* by variables.

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = a
```

`a` and `b` refer to the same object.  The `list` object has a *reference count* of 2, since there are two names referring to it.

```
a = {'x': 'y'}
```

`a` no longer refers to the same `list` object, instead it now refers to a `dict` object.  That decrements the reference count on the `list` object, but `b` still refers to it so the object's reference count is now 1.

```
b = None
```

That means that `b` now refers to the `None` object (which has a very high reference count, lots of names refer to `None`).  The `list` object gets its reference count decremented again and it falls to zero.  At this point the `list` object can be garbage collected and the memory freed (when that happens is not guaranteed).

See also [`sys.getrefcount`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getrefcount)

Answer (score 0):

**I am explaining you in a layman language so that you can understand it in an easy way.**

**Case-1**

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = a
print(b is a)
```

The value of `a` is `[1,2,3]`. Now we are assiging `[1,2,3]` to `b` also by `a`. So both have the same value, hence `b is a`  =  `True`.

Next step,

```
a = {'x': 'y'}
print(a is b)
```

Now you are changing the value of `a` to `{'x':'y'}` **but** our `b` is still same as `[1,2,3]`. So now `a is b` is `False`.

**Case-2** If you have done given below:-

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = a
print(b is a)
a = {'x': 'y'}
b = a  # Reassigning the value of b.
print(a is b)
```

After reassigning the value of `a`, I am also reassigning the value of `b`. 
Hence you will get `True` in both cases.

I hope this may help you.