# Why are some references in Python linked and others are not?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, reference

My question is best explained with an example:

```
a = 1
b = a
a = a + 1

print(a,b)
# result is:  2  1


a = [1,2]
b = a
a.append(3)

print(a,b)
# result is:  [1, 2, 3]  [1, 2, 3]
```

I'm trying to understand the logic or at least the rule behind this behavior.

Why are `a` and `b` linked when the original object is a `list()`, but not when it is a `int`? And in general, what are the types of objects that are linked/ not linked? Is there a general rule?

Comment: the short answer is thats just how it works. the longer answer involves talking about how different data types are represented in memory and optimization and ambiguity and stuff

Comment: Might be of relevance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56667280/if-two-variables-point-to-the-same-object-why-doesnt-reassigning-one-variable

Comment: Plain assignment always "links" (i.e. refers to the same object). The difference occurs with the operations. I.e. `+` on `int` creates a fresh `int` (this cannot be said in general for all possible types), while `append()` keeps the list you passed and doesn't create a new list.