# Python, variable importing between files

Tags: python, variables, scope, pygame, python-module

*Preamble: I feel I probably have wasted so much time for a simple situation...*

Now, I am making a game with pygame, and at some point, I wanted to split files into two, namely `main.py` and `configurations.py` in order to make it more readable.

Everything was going good, until I ran into this problem.

I will share whole code at the bottom, but I want to summarize first:

Now first of all, in `main.py`, I am importing by,

`from configurations import *`

now, the game loop on the `main.py` depends on the variable `running` by

```
while running:
    .......
    .......
    .......
```

And the variable `running` is initialized in `configurations.py` by,

```
# initialize some variables
running = True
```

So, the `main.py` has to be getting variable `running` because it does not give any error and uses it in `while running` statement.

In the main loop, there is a section where I check for events as follows,

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
        # check for closing window
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
```

This part works just as expected, it alters variable running and program gets out of the while loop.

Now, here comes the problematic part.

In one of the classes(Player class) there is a method as `decrease_HP`,

```
def decrease_HP(self):
        self.HP -= 1
        print("-1 HP", "Current HP:", self.HP)
        if self.HP <= 0:
            running = False
```

However, the point I could not figure out is that, it is not changing running variable properly, and game never stops(gets out of while loop). Here is one example output which shows the problem.

```
pygame 1.9.6
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
-1 HP Current HP: 2
-1 HP Current HP: 1
-1 HP Current HP: 0
-1 HP Current HP: -1
-1 HP Current HP: -2
-1 HP Current HP: -3
-1 HP Current HP: -4
-1 HP Current HP: -5
-1 HP Current HP: -6
```

So, I hope I could make it clear. I probably have a misunderstanding about importing variables or variable scopes.

By the way, I have tried adding `global running` above the `running = False` statement in `Player.decrease_HP` function.

Thanks in advance.

---

### Exact codes in the files

### main.py

```
# Pygame template - skeleton for a new pygame project
from configurations import *

# initiate some variables
max_bullet = 10


# initialize pygame and create window

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("CORONA RACE")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

player = Player()
all_sprites.add(player)


# initialize some variables
running = True

# have to use this because, otherwise, for the first SPACE key pressing, the newest_bullet is not defined yet.
newest_bullet = Bullet(0, 0)

# Game loop

while running:
    # keep loop running at the right speed
    clock.tick(FPS)
    # Process input (events)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # check for closing window
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        else:
            pass

    while len(mobs) != 5:
        m = Mob()
        all_sprites.add(m)
        mobs.add(m)

    keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    player.speedx = 0
    if keystate[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        player.speedx += player.SPEED
    if keystate[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        player.speedx -= player.SPEED
    if keystate[pygame.K_SPACE] and player.rect.top - newest_bullet.rect.bottom > BULLET_H + MARGIN and not len(bullets) >= max_bullet:
        newest_bullet = player.shoot()
    # BULLET_H refers to height of the bullet and margin refers to the minimum allowable margin between two consequent b
    # If there are more than 10 bullets at a time on the screen, then no more new bullets can be fired.
    if keystate[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
        running = False
    if random.randint(0, 14530) > 14470:
        power_up = PowerUp()
        all_sprites.add(power_up)
        powerups.add(power_up)

    hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, powerups, True)
    for pu in hits:
        power_up_funcs[pu.type](player)

    hits = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(mobs, bullets, True, True)
    for m in hits:
        pass

    hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, mobs, True)
    if hits:
        player.decrease_HP()

    # print(player.HP)

    # Update

    all_sprites.update()

    # Draw / render
    screen.fill(WHITE)
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    # *after* drawing everything, flip the display
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
raise SystemExit  # to exit python
```

---

### configurations.py

```
import pygame
import random

# define constants
WIDTH = 600
HEIGHT = 960
FPS = 30
BULLET_H = 24
BULLET_W = 8
POWERUP_H = 30
POWERUP_W = 30
MOB_W = 50
MOB_H = 80
MARGIN = 10

# define colors
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)
MAGENTA = (255, 0, 255)
CYAN = (0, 255, 255)

# create sprite groups
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()
powerups = pygame.sprite.Group()
mobs = pygame.sprite.Group()


# initialize some variables
running = True


# player sprite


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    SPEED = 15

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((100, 150))
        self.image.fill(CYAN)
        pygame.draw.circle(self.image, RED, (50, 75), 15, 5)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = WIDTH / 2
        self.rect.bottom = HEIGHT - 5
        self.speedx = 0
        self.HP = 3

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.speedx
        if self.rect.right > WIDTH:
            self.rect.right = WIDTH
        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0

    def shoot(self):
        bullet = Bullet(self.rect.centerx, self.rect.top)
        all_sprites.add(bullet)
        bullets.add(bullet)
        return bullet  # I need this to set the margin in continious fire.

    def change_color(self):
        pass

    def increase_HP(self):
        if self.HP <= 2:
            self.HP += 1
            print("+1 HP", "Current HP:", self.HP)
        else:
            print("HP IS ALREADY FULL", "Current HP:", self.HP)

    def decrease_HP(self):
        self.HP -= 1
        print("-1 HP", "Current HP:", self.HP)
        if self.HP <= 0:
            running = False


class Mob(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((MOB_W, MOB_H))
        self.image.fill(MAGENTA)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.left = random.randint(0, WIDTH - POWERUP_W)
        self.rect.bottom = random.randint(-2 * MOB_H, 0)

    def update(self):
        self.rect.y += 6
        if self.rect.top > HEIGHT:
            self.kill()

# Bullet sprite


class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((BULLET_W, BULLET_H))
        self.image.fill(RED)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = x
        self.rect.bottom = y
        self.speedx = 0
        self.speedy = -20

    def update(self):
        self.rect.y += self.speedy
        # kill it if it moves away from the screen
        if self.rect.bottom < 0:
            self.kill()  # built in method of pygame.sprite


# powerup sprite

power_up_funcs = [Player.increase_HP, print]  # container for to-do functs.


class PowerUp(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    SPEEDY = 8

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.type = random.randint(0, 1)  # [0,1] integer
        if self.type == 0:  # HP power up
            self.image = pygame.Surface((POWERUP_W, POWERUP_H))
            self.image.fill(GREEN)
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
            self.rect.left = random.randint(0, WIDTH - POWERUP_W)
            # self.rect.centerx = player.rect.centerx #debug
            self.rect.bottom = 0
        elif self.type == 1:  # shield
            self.image = pygame.Surface((POWERUP_W, POWERUP_H))
            self.image.fill(BLUE)
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
            self.rect.left = random.randint(0, WIDTH - POWERUP_W)
            # self.rect.centerx = player.rect.centerx # debug
            self.rect.bottom = 0
        else:
            pass

    def update(self):
        self.rect.y += self.SPEEDY
        if self.rect.top > HEIGHT:
            self.kill()
```

Comment: `global running` should have solved the problem.

Comment: Don't use globals to synchronise state. Yes, using globals is possible, no, doing globals right is not any less work. Have some object that represents the game instance, and set attribute on that.

Comment: @Barmar as I said in the question, I tried it, however could not get it working, where do you say to insert `global running` ?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi is it possible for you to suply an example as an answer?

Comment: The simplest change is not to do ``from configuration import *``, but just ``import configuration`` and using fully-qualified names, e.g. ``configuration.running``.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If two variables point to the same object, why doesn't reassigning one variable affect the other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56667280/if-two-variables-point-to-the-same-object-why-doesnt-reassigning-one-variable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TLDR: Use `import configuration` and fully qualified names, e.g. `configuration.running`.

If a function inside `configuration` needs to modify a top-level value, it must use `global`.

```
def decrease_HP(self):
    global running
    self.HP -= 1
    print("-1 HP", "Current HP:", self.HP)
    if self.HP <= 0:
        running = False
```

---

Using `from configurations import running` (or equivalent via `... import *`) in `main` binds the *value* of `configurations.running` to a new name `main.running`. While these names initially share the same value, re-assigning either breaks this equivalency. This is exactly the same as rebinding other names.

```
>>> a = 1
>>> b = a  # a and b point to same value
>>> a == b
True
>>> b = 2  # rebind only b
>>> a == b
False
```

To make changes visible across the application, one should use *an object* an modify its value. A common example are containers, such as lists.

```
>>> a = [1]
>>> b = a  # a and b point to same value
>>> a == b
True
>>> b[0] = 2  # modify content of value of b
>>> a == b
True
>>> a[0] == b[0]  # content is the same
True
```

Since modules are objects, it is possible to use them directly to store state.

```
>>> import configuration
>>> b = configuration  # configuration and b point to same value
>>> configuration == b
True
>>> b.running = False  # modify content of value of b
>>> configuration == b
True
>>> configuration.running == b.running  # content is the same
True
```

---

Functions have local scope. Any assignment to a name inside a function implicitly declares the target as local to the function.

```
>>> running = True
>>> def stop():
...    running = False
...
>>> stop()  # changes only running inside the function
>>> running
True
```

This can be made visible by accessing a local name before it has a value.

```
>>> running = True
>>> def stop():
...    print(running)
...    running = False
...
>>> stop()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'running' referenced before assignment
```

By declaring the name `global`, no local name is created. The global value can be directly read and written.

```
>>> running = True
>>> def stop():
...    global running
...    print(running)
...    running = False
...
>>> stop()  # will print the global value before the change
True
>>> running  # global value was changed
False
```

Comment: thanks for such an effort! I will read it now, and then look at your other answer which you linked.