# Is there any problem between using the pop method and for loops when we they are not using the same variables as each other?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Is there any problem between using the pop method and for loops when we they are not using the same variables as each other?

This is my code.

```
def tagsnotused(self):

    tag_list = self.Tags
    tag_list_Names = []
    # ~ append list by object Name to use index method later
    for Tag in self.Tags:
        tag_list_Names.append(Tag.Name)

    for Tag in self.Tags:   
        # ~ a = 0 tag processed, a = 1 tag not processed
        a = 0
        # ~ Adding tails
        TagName0 = Tag.Name + "."
        TagName1 = Tag.Name + "["
        TagName2 = Tag.Name + ")"
        # ~ Loop for looking conditions
        for Prog in self.Program:
            for Rout in Prog.Routine:
                for Rng in Rout.Rung:
                    # ~ Condicional para encontrar tag
                    if (Rng.Content.find(TagName0) != -1 or Rng.Content.find(TagName1) != -1 or  Rng.Content.find(TagName2) != -1) and a == 0:
                        a = 1
                        index = tag_list_Names.index(Tag.Name)
                        value = tag_list.pop(indice)
                        tag_list_Names.pop(indice)



    return tag_list
```

The problem is that everytime I am making `value = tag_list.pop(indice)` the for loop is jumping one element and going to the next one.

`self.Tags` is as follows `list[_object]`

Comment: Note that  ``tag_list = self.Tags`` does not create a copy of ``self.Tags``, it merely refers to the value of ``self.Tags`` with an additional name. See also [If two variables point to the same object, why doesn't reassigning one variable affect the other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56667280/if-two-variables-point-to-the-same-object-why-doesnt-reassigning-one-variable)

Answer (score 2):

You are getting bitten by the mutability of lists.

`taglist = self.Tags` causes `taglist` to point towards the same list as `self.Tags`

In order to fix this you could use the `copy` module.

`from copy import copy`

And then to create the copy of your list use `taglist = copy(self.Tags)`.

You could also simply use `taglist = self.Tags[:]`.

What's happening in your loop is you are iterating over `self.Tags` and when you `pop()` the element out of `taglist` it removes it from `self.Tags` as well since they are both pointing at the same object. This causes your for loop to "jump ahead" since you now have one less element in it.

Comment: Note that lists have a ``.copy`` method.

Comment: Depends on what version of python 3 he is on. I believe earlier versions don't have it.

Comment: True. The ``.copy`` method was [added in Python 3.3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types).

Comment: Hello everyone, I am using 3.6. Thanks. I am gonna to check if I can fix the problem.

Comment: That´s Ok. It is working. Thank you so much.