# Trying to understand recursion/backtracking, simple inelegant Sudoku example

Tags: python, recursion, depth-first-search, backtracking, sudoku

**[This post was poorly received so I've made some suggested edits to try to improve it for posterity. I hope it's helpful to anyone who finds it in the future!]**

I have been trying to understand recursion/backtracking/DFS using a simple Sudoku example. I'm not really interested in the Sudoku example per se, so per suggestion I've minimized the example below to just a 2x2 sudoku board in order to just focus on the point that confuses me about recursion (thank you @MisterMiyagi for the suggestion).

In the code below, I have a helper function `check_board` which takes a 2x2 matrix and checks if any numbers repeat in its rows and columns (i.e., checks if the 2x2 sudoku entered is valid). Then the function `solve_sudoku` is what I understand to be a standard DFS/backtracking algorithm to solve the sudoku by picking the first empty position (represented by a 0), and trying both values 1 and 2 in it, recursively looking for a solution.

So with input `[[0,0], [0,2]]` the output should be `[[[2,1],[1,2]]`, but I was receiving the output `False`.

@ThierryLathuille helped by noticing the problem in the code: after trying each possible descendant node (in this case, by trying both values 1, 2), I missed the "backtracking" step, and need to add a line resetting the value to 0, meaning that square in the matrix would be stuck in a 2 for all subsequent calls (or, in the original 9x9 example, stuck at a 9):

> When you see that the last value you tried in a square can't lead to a valid solution, you try the next one, until you reach 9. At this point, you return and go back to incrementing the value in the previous square, but you current one still contains the value 9, so it is considered as non available for the next attempts.
>
> You just have to put it back to its original value of 0 before returning:

Now here's where I'm still confused and the point of the question: I am trying to think about the recursion like a tree. Once one of the nodes has tried every value for a square and its descendant nodes have all come back `False`, doesn't it just report `False` back up to its parent? Why would anyone else look at that board with the 2 again?

If you can help with my understanding of recursion, I'd really appreciate it!

**Edit**: @ThierryLathuille answered the question again in a comment! Thanks so much!

> Note that when calling your function recursively, you don't pass copies of the board, but only manipulate the same board everywhere. As your code worked, each time you explored a branch of the tree, all the squares you touched during the exploration were left with a non-zero value, so they were not considered as free any more.

I had the mistaken idea that whenever a function is called in recursion, it gets a new copy of all its variables to act on. Which of course it does, but not of the input! Another fix to the code would be to use Python's `copy` module with the line `copy_board = copy.deepcopy(board)` and operate on and return `copy_board` at each instantiation of the function, which is what I mistakenly thought Python  always did in recursion.

Maybe this has something to do with pass by value versus pass by reference, and Python is pass by reference always? Any more discussion on the subject is still appreciated!

---

Here's the broken code with line that fixes it commented out:

```
def check_board(board: list):
    for i in chars:
        for j in chars:
            for k in chars:
                if k == j:
                    continue
                if board[i][j] == board[i][k] and board[i][j] != 0:
                    return False
                if board[j][i] == board[k][i] and board[j][i] != 0:
                    return False
    return True

def solve_sudoku(board: list):
    chars = range(2)
    if not check_board(board):
        return False
    for i in chars:
        for j in chars:
            if board[i][j] == 0:
                for a in chars:
                    board[i][j] = a+1
                    if solve_sudoku(board):
                        return solve_sudoku(board)
                # uncommenting this next line fixes the algorithm
                #board[i][j] = 0
                return False
    return board


board = [[0,0],[0,2]]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(solve_sudoku(board))
```

Output: 
`False`

Comment: This is *a lot* of code. Please help us help you by removing unhelpful code and comments, and more explicitly describing your problem – for example, which function is recursive? If you wonder about recursion, can you reduce the example to the minimum needed to reproduce your problem? Why do you think it's a problem of recursion instead of one of the many checks? Do we actually need ``check_board``, with its 6-nested ``for`` loop, when you already provide a board that you (hopefully) have checked yourself?

Comment: @MarcelBesixdouze Please don't edit your post to say "solved". By doing so, and removing key parts of the initial question that was answered, the thread loses context for future visitors who won't be able to understand what you were originally having trouble with. See these meta threads: [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309237/dealing-with-questions-that-are-edited-after-my-answer-has-been-accepted) and [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299405/should-a-question-edit-be-rolled-back-if-it-appears-to-be-a-follow-up-to-an-answ)

Comment: Thank you very much for making these changes. These may be helpful to understand how Python passes around objects: [Are python variables pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13530998/are-python-variables-pointers-or-else-what-are-they), [Changing an object pointed to by two variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56667280/if-two-variables-point-to-the-same-object-why-doesnt-reassigning-one-variable),  [How are arguments passes in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you see that the last value you tried in a square can't lead to a valid solution, you try the next one, until you reach 9. At this point, you return and go back to incrementing the value in the previous square, but your current one still contains the value 9, so it is considered as non available for the next attempts.

You just have to put it back to its original value of 0 before returning:

```
if board[3*a+c][3*b+d] == board[3*a+e][3*b+f] and board[3*a+c][3*b+d] != 0:
    board[i][j] = 0
    return False
```

Output:

```
[[4, 8, 6, 9, 1, 5, 7, 3, 2], 
 [7, 2, 5, 4, 6, 3, 1, 9, 8],
 [3, 9, 1, 7, 8, 2, 4, 5, 6], 
 [5, 6, 4, 1, 9, 7, 2, 8, 3],
 [9, 7, 3, 6, 2, 8, 5, 1, 4],
 [8, 1, 2, 5, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9],
 [2, 5, 7, 8, 4, 9, 3, 6, 1], 
 [1, 3, 8, 2, 5, 6, 9, 4, 7],
 [6, 4, 9, 3, 7, 1, 8, 2, 5]]
```

which is the correct answer.

It takes a very long time to reach it, though (about 30 seconds or so...), as a lot of parts of your code, especially the checks for the existence of duplicates in rows/colums/blocks are very inefficient. Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1541797/how-do-i-check-if-there-are-duplicates-in-a-flat-list) for ideas of efficient ways.

Comment: Thanks so much! This is really great, but I'm still a bit lost as to what's happening. I am trying to think about the recursion like a tree. Once one of the nodes has tried every value for a square and its descendant nodes have all come back False, doesn't it just report False back up to its parent? Why would anyone else look at that board with the 9 again?

Comment: Note that when calling your function recursively, you don't pass copies of the board, but only manipulate the same board everywhere. As your code worked, each time you explored a branch of the tree, all the squares you touched during the exploration were left with a non-zero value, so they were not considered as free any more.

Comment: Fantastic! I definitely get it now. That makes perfect sense, and I'll also look into implementing a call with a copy and see how that changes it for my understanding. Thank you so much, this has been so helpful.