# list.extend() randomly failing to add results during a for loop

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop, random

I've been banging my head at a program which repeatedly chooses the largest item in a list and copies it over the entire list, adding a bit of variation each time. It feels like it should be easy, but one element ends up blank every time. Here's the code, with the important part separated:

```
import random as r
alice = []
bob = []
cathy= []
davos = []
ezekiel = []
francesco = []
graham = []
genVar = 0.25
classroom = [alice, bob, cathy, davos, ezekiel, francesco, graham]
for i in classroom:
    skill = r.random()
    i.append(skill)
    i.append(1-skill)
a = 0

while a < 10:
    best = max(classroom, key=lambda x:x[0]*x[1])
    for i in classroom:
        i.clear()
        i.extend(best)
        print(best)
        i[0] += r.uniform(-1*genVar, genVar)
        i[1] += r.uniform(-1*genVar, genVar)

    a+=1
    print(best)
```

When I run the cde, the error I get is like so:

```
[0.5598973199094259, 0.44010268009057407]
[0.5598973199094259, 0.44010268009057407]
[0.5598973199094259, 0.44010268009057407]
[]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Leafy/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/multiplierlearner.py", line 24, in <module>
    i[0] += r.uniform(-1*genVar, genVar)
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The weird thing is, when I run the code a second time, I get this result instead:

```
[0.6459806429424123, 0.3540193570575877]
[]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Leafy/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/multiplierlearner.py", line 23, in <module>
    i[0] += r.uniform(-1*genVar, genVar)
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The number of completed elements changes every time, and it's driving me insane. Any help is appreciated, and let me know if there's any more information I should put up.

Comment: Since both ``i`` and ``best`` are in ``classroom``, it can occur that ``i is best`` which means ``i.clear()`` also clears ``best``.

Comment: I see how i could be inside classroom, but isn't best its own separate variable outside of classroom?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to clone or copy a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list)

Comment: Might also be of interest: [If two variables point to the same object, why doesn't reassigning one variable affect the other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56667280/if-two-variables-point-to-the-same-object-why-doesnt-reassigning-one-variable) and [Are python variables pointers? or else what are they?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13530998/are-python-variables-pointers-or-else-what-are-they/57380719#57380719)

Answer (score 0):

A simple modification will be required as:

```
for i in classroom:
        if i != best:
            i.clear()
            i.extend(best)
```

I tried your code and modified it for better understanding,

```
import random as r
alice = []
bob = []
cathy= []
davos = []
ezekiel = []
francesco = []
graham = []
genVar = 0.25
classroom = [alice, bob, cathy, davos, ezekiel, francesco, graham]
for i in classroom:
    skill = r.randint(0,100)
    i.append(skill)
    i.append(skill-1)
a = 0

while a < 10:
    print("Iteration number",a)
    print()
    best = max(classroom, key=lambda x:x[1])
    print("best",best)

    print("max:",max(classroom, key=lambda x:x[1]))

    print("clasroom",classroom)
    for i in classroom:
        if i != best:
            i.clear()
            i.extend(best)
        print("best in iteration",best)
        i[0] += r.uniform(-1*genVar, genVar)
        i[1] += r.uniform(-1*genVar, genVar)

    a+=1
    print()
    print("best after iteration",best)
    print()
```