# How to update values in a for loop in python?

Tags: python

Say I have a list of variables with the following values

```py
a, b, c = 1, 2, 3
```

How can I update the value of `a,b,c` in a for loop?

I've tried the following but it doesn't work.

```py
for v in (a, b, c):
    v = v + 1
```

The values for `a,b,c` remains unchanged after the process

```py
print(a, b, c)
# [1] 1 2 3
```

Comment: I think you'll have to do it manually. Here a, b, c are called by reference, therefore, the update only exists for the local variable `v` and not `a, b, c`

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you'd like to achieve, why the `for loop`?

Comment: @CosmosZhu What do you mean by called by reference? I'm not familiar with this and googling just makes me more confused.

Comment: @Cosmos547 Simply it means that during the for loop the operations do not apply to the original variable.

Comment: @CosmosZhu Ok, but I have many variables to update. Doing them one by one will be really undesiring...

Comment: You're literally assigning to the variable `v`, that indeed won't change the variables `a`, `b` nor `c`. You'd have to assign to the variable *by name*, but once you go there, you're usually on the wrong track. There are probably way better approaches to whatever problem you're trying to implement here that render this issue moot.

Comment: @Cosmos547 Maybe consider putting the variables in a list? List variables are accessed by reference and your for loop will work.

Comment: @CosmosZhu Thanks, I think others have already given solutions based on lists.

Comment: @Cosmos547 No problem. Yeah, that's one way to do it. : )

Comment: Related: [If two variables point to the same object, why doesn't reassigning one variable affect the other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56667280/if-two-variables-point-to-the-same-object-why-doesnt-reassigning-one-variable)

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to achieve? Surely your use-case is not "increase these variables", but rather the variables and their increase stand for something?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I need to perform the same transformation to a large set of variables (which are attributes of an object). Using a for loop to go through them doesn't change the variable. Which got me curious to why and how can I do it elegantly.

Comment: @Cosmos547 If they are attributes, then you can programmatically set them as ``setattr(obj, name, getattr(obj, name) + 1)``. Of course, details may vary depending on the specific use-case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
a, b, c = [v+1 for v in (a,b,c)]
```

Answer (score 3):

### Using lists or dicts

If you have many *related* variables, a good choice is to store them in a `list` or `dict`. This has many advantages over having many separate variables:

1. Easy to perform an operation on all of them (like updating, printing, saving).
2. Doesn't litter your code/namespace with an abundance of variables.
3. Better maintainable code: Less places to change, if you need to add/remove a variable.

### Update values in a for loop

```
# example using a dict

# give them a meaningful name
counters = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}

for key in counters:
    counters[key] += 1
```

### Comparing this to updating separate variables in a loop

`a,b,c = [v+1 for v in (a,b,c)]` This creates an intermediate list with the new values, assigns these to your variables and then throws away the list again. This is an unnecessary intermediate step, but not a big issue.

The real problem with this is, that you still have to write out every variable name **twice**. It's hardly an improvement over just writing `a,b,c = a+1,b+1,c+1`.