# why does clearing a list also clears all variables set to equal that list?

Tags: python-3.x

Using Python 3.8.10

I can from a C++ background and was doing a project in python3 where I noticed this:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = a
a = [8]
print(b)  // this gives [1,2,3,4]
```

but when I do a.clear

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = a
a.clear()
print(b)  // this gives []
```

why is that?

Comment: FWIW, `.clear()` is pretty rarely used -- I've never used it personally.

Comment: If you do this in C++, the exact same thing should happen. `a` and `b` refer to the same list.

Comment: This is probably one of the better answers that explains this phenomenon [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56667280/if-two-variables-point-to-the-same-object-why-doesnt-reassigning-one-variable)

Comment: @MateenUlhaq What data type do you think is the C++ equivalent of Python's `list`?

Comment: @KellyBundy `std::vector<int>& b = a;` https://replit.com/@SicariusNoctis/stdvector-reference#main.cpp

Comment: @MateenUlhaq `std::vector<int>&`? Ok. But you didn't do that for `a`. I tried changing `a` to `std::vector<int>&` as well, didn't compile.

Comment: @KellyBundy What do you think is the C++ equivalent of Python's `=`? I think the closest is `T& b = a;` for all non-primitive types. Similarly, python variables are similar to the type `T&`. If you want the types to match, try declaring a new vector `v` to store the data, then set `std::vector<int>& a = v;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second example, `b` is a reference to `a`. `a.clear()` mutates the underlying list to be empty, so `b` will also be empty. In the first example, `a = [8]` will assign a new list to `a`, but `b` is still pointing to the previous reference to `a`.

If I were to translate this to C++, the first example might look something like this. (I don't use C++ that often so this code might be weird)

```cpp
std::vector<int> v1 = {1, 2, 3, 4};
std::vector<int>* a = &v1;
std::vector<int>* b = a;
std::vector<int> v2 = {8};
a = &v2;
```

The second example would look like

```cpp
std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4};
std::vector<int>* a = &v;
std::vector<int>* b = a;
(*a).clear();
```

Comment: I see, so essentially all variables I make in python are just pointers

Comment: yeah I think that's a good way to think about it

Comment: It would make more sense to use `std::vector<int>& b = v;` since non-primitive types are much more like references than pointers in python.