# i changed a variable and that should change other variable but it didnt change

Tags: python-3.x

Actually I already solved this problem but I want to solve it in another approach. I have a list `[11,2,5,23,15,8,7,6,19,21,18]` and variables

```
 pointer = 0
 number = list[pointer]
```

I iterated it using for loop, so for each number in that loop, I added the pointer by 1. So normally the variable `number` should change too right? because the pointer changed but it didn't change it still `list[0]` that is 11.
do you guys know why did this happen? I believe there is something I didn't know about changing the variable

Comment: Can you please post your full code?

Comment: Python doesn't have pointers, and your code doesn't change anything. Please clearly explain what you are doing, what effect you are seeing and what you have expected instead. Note that ``list[pointer]`` immediately evaluates to a *value* that has no relation to ``list`` or ``pointer`` (i.e. ``number`` is not an expression).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are python variables pointers? or else what are they?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13530998/are-python-variables-pointers-or-else-what-are-they)

Comment: I am so sorry to all of you that tried to answer my question because i didnt explain it clearly. I already real all your answer and thank you. I understand more about python

Answer (score -1):

I can't diagnose your error without seeing your code, but here are 2 ways to do it.  The first uses the manual increment method you described and the second takes advantage of an iterator:

```
my_list = [11,2,5,23,15,8,7,6,19,21,18]

#Parsing list by manual increment method:
x = 0    
while True:
    print(my_list[x])
    x += 1
    if x > len(my_list)-1:
        break
print('\n')

#This is how I would iterate through list:
for x in range(0,len(my_list)):
    print(my_list[x])
```

Comment: The idiomatic way to iterate a list is ``for x in my_list``. Either way, that does not seem to be the goal of the question.