# How to define a function to automatically copy a class and delete them without input argument?

Tags: python-3.x, function, class, arguments

There's a python module module1.py, inside this module there was a class1, and a variable defined as x=class1() and y=class1(). After several operation the object x contained data.

How to write a function clean_up() in module1 such that

```
module1.clean_up() #takes no input argument
```

would reset x into the empty class1() and make y contain the value of x?
I have tried to use

```
def clean_up():
    y=copy(x);
    del x;
    x=class1();
```

However, this does not make a copy of x and pass it to y, nor does it run successfully and clear x.
An error returned as

```
module1.clean_up()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Hecke_variable' referenced before assignment
```

i.e. Both x and y were treated as local variables.
But in a previous post, [Python class instance changed during local function variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65809768/python-class-instance-changed-during-local-function-variable), class was mutable and any changes to a class instance inside a function would reflect outside the function as well.

Why wasn't the function clean_up() run successfully? How to write clean_up()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables defined in a function are bound to that function local scope. If you wish to affect variables in outer scope, you need to let python know by using the **global** keyword.

```
def clean_up():
    import copy

    global x, y

    y = copy.deepcopy(x)
    x = Class1()
```