# Why the copy of iter() pointing to the same location?

Tags: python, iteration

```
x=5
y=x
x=7
# Changing the value of x does not effect the value of y
```

As a simple example both `x`&`y` have different memory location so changing one does not effect other

But in the code below `next(y)` is giving `4` why?
According to my logic it must be `1` where I am going wrong

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
x=iter(a)
y=x

print(next(x))
print(next(x))
print(next(x))

print(next(y))
```

Comment: You are mistaken. ```y = x``` will assign the reference to ```y``` which points to the **same** object in the memory

Comment: If you need to duplicate iterable use https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee

Comment: That means the next() function changes are reflected on the object iter(a) 
@Sujay

Comment: Assignment never copies data in Python.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are python variables pointers? or else what are they?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13530998/are-python-variables-pointers-or-else-what-are-they)

Comment: If you assign a new value to `x` like you did in your first example - `x = iter(a); y = x; x = iter(a)` - and then do your `next`s, your second code will behave as you expected.

Comment: "As a simple example both x&y have different memory location" No, they do not. Both `x` and `y` are *referring to the same object*. However, `x=7` **does not mutate whatever object `x` was referring to*, it just re-assigns the name `x` to a new object

Comment: x is just a generator object, and y is x, so whenevr next of x is called,  value of the next(x) updated both in x and y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example

```py
x=5
y=x
x=7
```

After the second line, `x` and `y` point to the same object, that is `5`.
When you change `x`, `y` stays 5 because you didn't change the object `5` itself, but you just changed  the location to which `x` points to. However, in the second example,

```py
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
x=iter(a)
y=x

print(next(x))
print(next(x))
print(next(x))

print(next(y))
```

`x` and `y` still point to the same location. But when you call the `next` method, you are changing the object at that location, you are not making a new object at a different location.

Comment: `you are changing the object at that location`  the object here is iter(a)

Answer (score 2):

Doing `y=x` creates named reference `y` that basically points to the same memory location as pointed by variable `x`, you can use `id`  (which gives memory location representation) builtin to verify it:

```py
>>> a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
>>> x=iter(a)
>>> y=x
>>> id(x)
1714277910984
>>> id(y)
1714277910984
```

If you want a copy of the iterator `x`, you can use `deepcopy` function from `copy` module:

```py
>>> from copy import deepcopy
>>> y = deepcopy(x)
>>> id(x)
1714277910984
>>> id(y)
1714135198792
```

Now `x` and `y` are two different iterators:

```py
>>> next(x)
1
>>> next(y)
1
>>> next(x)
2
>>> next(y)
2
```

Comment: Note, a regular `copy.copy` should work.

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that not every iterator can be meaningfully copied. For example, copying a ``map`` iterator will just return the original.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga *Might* even be [preferable](https://tio.run/##rY7BCsIwDIbveYqAh7UQZO3UTcEnEQ9DK/awNdQe2qev3XAiHsWcku/nDx@ncHdj07HP@ebdgBfHCe3Azge8GsPTTTMFYG/HIKoFHyoJPR7xpEhTQxva0o5a6mhPqj5DLJENxoteQir7UhOx1NbsWNTy9XI0MRQscZoVzvCB@jNN36l6@/zg8kcPDTk/AQ).

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode yeah, I guess it depends on whether you need deep copy semantics, or if a shallow copy is necessary (or merely sufficient)\

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Actually it [seems to](https://tio.run/##VYw7DsIwEAX7PcWWtvQKQviEgpOgFBY4IhK2V2YL@/SOKUCinDeaJ1WfKY6T5NaWnALfk1Reg6Ss/PBePkzk@Mq3AXuMOOCIE86YcMGwm6l0FZyY5ZWcgp2l2pdvaoolyWtU01/f/KPoi3b3h9Xa1jY) give a separate independent iterator.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode Try it with just a ``copy.copy`` instead.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Just means we need to use the appropriate copying method for a meaningful copy :-). And still a [new object](https://tio.run/##HYwxDoMwEAT7e8WVtrQF4CRAwUtQCgsJBSnmTsaF/XrHoVvNaFZL@sjpJo217lECb6KFj6AS072JPC@89hjg8MATL4yYMKPv3pSbCl7N/hWfwN5SaeSfmWxJ43Em094uzrbWHw), not the original.