# I'm trying to understand how reference works in python

Tags: python, list, reference, append

After line 7, I haven't written a single line of code which mentions the list named 'outer'. However, if you execute it, you'll see that the 'outer' (i.e, the nested lists inside it) list would change/update due to lines 10 and 12...

I'm guessing it has something to do with reference vs value. My question is, why didn't line 13 effect (change/update) the 'outer' list the same way that lines 7 and 10 did? I'm trying to undertand this concept. How do I go about it. I know there's a lot of resources online.. but I don't even know what to google. Please help.

```
inner = []
outer = []

lis = ['a', 'b', 'c']

inner.append(lis[0])
outer.append(inner) <<---- Line 7 <<

print(outer)
inner.append(lis[1]) <<---- Line 10 <<
print(outer)
inner.append(lis[2]) <<---- Line 12 <<
print(outer)
lis[2] = 'x' <<---- Line *******13******* <<
print(outer)
```

Comment: Append is to add a new element into your empty list, that's why your `outer` was updated. On the other hand, your line 13 is to update the list `lis`, not the `outer`, so that's why your `outer` list was not affected at all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are Python variables pointers? Or else, what are they?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13530998/are-python-variables-pointers-or-else-what-are-they)

Answer (score 0):

This is a boiled-down version of your example:

```
some_list = []
a = 2

some_list.append(a)
a = 3

print(some_list)  # output: [2]
print(a)  # output: 3
```

If we follow your original logic, you would expect `some_list` to contain the value `3` when we print it. But the reality is that we never appended `a` itself to the list. Instead, writing `some_list.append(a)` means *appending the value **referenced** by `a` to the list `some_list`*.

Remember, variables are simply **references** to a value. Here's the same snippet as above, but with an explanation of what's referencing what.

```
some_list = []  # the name "some_list" REFERENCES an empty list
a = 2  # the name "a" REFERENCES the integer value 2

some_list.append(a)  # we append the value REFERENCED BY "a" 
                     # (the integer 2) to the list REFERENCED 
                     # BY "some_list". That list is not empty
                     # anymore, holding the value [2]

a = 3  # the name "a" now REFERENCES the integer value 3. This
       # has no implications on the list REFERENCED BY "some_list".
       # We simply move the "arrow" that pointed the name "a" to
       # the value 2 to its new value of 3

print(some_list)  # output: [2]
print(a)  # output: 3
```

The key aspect to understand here is that **variables are simply references to a value**. Writing `some_list.append(a)` does not mean "place the variable `a` into the list" but rather "place the *value that the variable `a` references at this moment in time* into the list". Variables cannot keep track of other variables, only the values that they are a reference to.

This becomes even clearer if we append to `some_list` a second time, after modifying the value that `a` references:

```
some_list = []
a = 2

some_list.append(a)
a = 3
some_list.append(a)

print(some_list)  # output: [2, 3]
print(a)  # output: 3
```

Answer (score -1):

In Python, when you store a list in  variable you don't store the list itself, but a reference to a list somewhere in the computer's RAM. If you say

```py
a = [0, 1, 2]
b = a
c = 3
```

then both `a` and `b` will be references to the same list as you set `b` to `a`, which is a reference to a list. Then, modifying `a` will modify `b` and vice-versa. `c`, however, is an *integer*; it works differently. It's like that:

```
  ┌───┐
a │ █━┿━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓ ┌───┬───┬───┐
  └───┘               ┠→│ 0 │ 1 │ 2 │
  ┌───┐               ┃ └───┴───┴───┘
b │ █━┿━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┛
  └───┘
  ┌───┐
c │ 3 │
  └───┘
```

`a` and `b` are *references* to a same list, but `c` is an *pointer to an integer* which is copied (the integer) when you say `d = c`. The reference to it, however, is not copied.

So, let's go back to your program. When you say `inner.append(lis[n])` you add the value at the end of the list `inner`. You don't add the reference to the item #2 of the list `lis` but you create a copy of the value itself and add to the list the reference to this copy!
If you modify `lis`, then it will have an impact only on variables that are references to `lis`.

If you want `inner` to be modified if you modify `lis`, then replace the `inner.append(lis[n])`s by `inner.append(lis)`.

Comment: "``c`` is an integer and is the value itself and not a reference to it" That's not true, and it's a common misconception. The reference implementation uses C pointers that refer to objects; even if other implementations use a different scheme (e.g. PyPy's tagged pointers) they still have all the *semantics* of referencing. ``c`` also refers to its target, there is just no way to *modify* its target.

Comment: Thanks @MisterMiyagi, I corrected my answer.

Comment: ``a``, ``b`` and ``c`` all are the same kind. If ``c`` is a pointer, so are ``a`` and ``b``.

Comment: Yes, but `a` and `b` are pointers to a list where `c` is a pointer to an integer. Pointers to lists work differently than pointers to integers.

Comment: "Pointers to lists work differently than pointers to integers." No they don't! They're all ``PyObject*`` pointers. The things they *point to* work differently from each other, but the pointers themselves are exactly the same.

Comment: Yes, you're right... But then, why will `a` be modified if I do `b = a` and then `b[0] += 1` if both `a` and `b` are lists, and why will `a` not be modified if they are integers? (well, pointers to)

Comment: Because an integer is *immutable*. It cannot be modified. In your example, the thing *pointed to* has its value changed, not the thing *pointing*. ``b[0] += 1`` modifies the first element of the list pointed to by ``b``; it does not modify the name ``b``.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I understand now.