# Why does the linked list pointer inside Python list become separate?

Tags: python, list

After saving a pointer to a linked list node in a variable 'head', I inserted the 'head' inside a Python list (named 'tail'). Then, even if I traversed the linked list by accessing the 'head' variable in the Python list, I can still access the head of the linked list by accessing 'head'. One can check by comparing the two ids : id(head) != id(tail[0]).

Why is it so?

```
head = ListNode(0)          # Stored a pointer to a ListNode(0)
tail = [head]               # Assigned a pointer to a Python list having a 'head' as an element
tail[0].next = ListNode(1)  # Attached a ListNode(1)
tail[0] = tail[0].next      # Traversed
id(head) == id(tail[0])     # Gives 'False'; two ids are unequal.

# FYI - ListNode definition
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next
```

Comment: What did you expect and why? `head` is still `head`, but `tail` only contains `ListNode(1)`.

Comment: You set `tail[0]` to `tail[0].next`, which is `ListNode(1)`. `head` is still set to `ListNode(0)` because you never assigned it anything else. They are referring to different objects.

Comment: For the same reason that `tail = [1]; tail[0] = 2; tail[0] is 1` is false. You changed what `tail[0]` refers to.

Comment: You might do well to read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: Might be worth reading: [Are Python variables pointers? Or else, what are they?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13530998/are-python-variables-pointers-or-else-what-are-they) TLDR: ``head`` is *not* what you think of as a pointer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, folks! I am finally convinced by pythontutor.com visualizer that the head and tail[0] points to different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tail[0].next = ListNode(1)  # Attached a ListNode(1)
tail[0] = tail[0].next      # Traversed
```

in terms of what happens to the array is just

```
tail[0] = ListNode(1)
```

And then you are somehow confused why that is not equal to `head`?! Because `head` is still `ListNode(0)`.

What is `True` is `id(head.next) == id(tail[0])`.