# for loop doesn't modify a global variable python

Tags: python, for-loop, global-variables

I've declared some dicts that contain keys for each NFL team and an object related to them.

Now I'm trying to modify those dicts in order to have a key called 'teams' where I would put the previous values of the dict, and 5 new keys named 2018 to 2022

```
tmp = ['Packers', 'Vikings', 'Lions', 'Bears']
NFC_North = {name: team(name=name) for name in tmp}

tmp = ['Buccaneers', 'Saints', 'Panthers', 'Falcons']
NFC_South = {name: team(name=name) for name in tmp}

tmp = ['Cowboys', 'Giants', 'Eagles', 'Commanders']
NFC_East = {name: team(name=name) for name in tmp}

tmp = ['Rams', 'Cardinals', 'Seahawks', '49ers']
NFC_West = {name: team(name=name) for name in tmp}

NFC = [NFC_North, NFC_South, NFC_East, NFC_West]
```

I've tried implementing a for loop that iterates over every team and does what I described before. But when I check if the dict was modified, it reimained the same

```
print(NFC[0])

for i in NFC:
    i = {
        'teams': i,
        '2022': 0,
        '2021': 0,
        '2020': 0,
        '2019': 0,
        '2018': 0
    }
    print(NFC_North, i)
```

I checked the id's and I realized that items[i](suppose i = 0) is not the same object as NFC_North. Even though NFC_North is actually the first element in the NFC list

My code works as expected inside the loop, but I can't modify the actual element I want to modify and I don't know why it doesen't get modified and how can I do to modify it

I'm new to programming and this is my first time posting here, hope I wrote it in the right way. Thanks to you all in advance

**Edit**: Many of you are recommending me to do the following:

```
for i in range(len(NFC)):
    NFC[i] = {
        'teams': NFC[i],
        '2022': 0,
        '2021': 0,
        '2020': 0,
        '2019': 0,
        '2018': 0
    }
```

But the output remains the same. Correct me if I'm doing something wrong but I think this is the solution everybody is redirecting me towards, it's behaving just the same

Comment: You're looping over the values, which don't modify the original container. Use `for i in range(len(NFC)): NFC[i] = ...`.

Comment: Related/possible duplicate: [Are Python variables pointers? Or else, what are they?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13530998/11082165)

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal please take I look to what I just edited. I did what you suggested but my output remains the same

Comment: Works perfectly when I apply the fix, adding the dummy function `def team(name): return name`. What output are you getting?

Comment: @Brian not really. I tried looping through the indexes as one answer on that post suggest and my output remains the same. I've just edited it on the post,  maybe I'm writting something wrong

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal my output is: {'Packers': <__main__.team object at 0x00000268CAEA06D0>, 'Vikings': <__main__.team object at 0x00000268CAEA0130>, 'Lions': <__main__.team object at 0x00000268CAEA0370>, 'Bears': <__main__.team object at 0x00000268CAEA0040>}

When I expected: {'teams': {'Packers': <__main__.team object at 0x00000268CB819970>, 'Vikings': <__main__.team object at 0x00000268CB819BE0>, 'Lions': <__main__.team object at 0x00000268CB819B20>, 'Bears': <__main__.team object at 0x00000268CB819340>}, '2022': 0, '2021': 0, '2020': 0, '2019': 0, '2018': 0}

Comment: Is there any other code which you haven't shown which would cause this discrepency? What is the `team()` function?

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal here it is

class team:
    def __init__ (self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.AP = {
                2018: 0,
                2019: 0,
                2020: 0,
                2021: 0,
                2022: 0
            }

I've written other lines but it is just defining the divisions and assigning values to teams.AP

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal i revised it again and i've tried by printing NFC[0] and it works well. the issue was when i printed NFC_North(which is the variable listed as index 0 in NFC). I defined NFC as = [NFC_North, NFC_East, NFC_West, NFC_South]. So i'm supposing that creates a copy of  the elements, not their pointer. I'm still having issue because i want to call NFC_North by its name, not by iterating over NFC. Is there any solution? This would have been much easier in C lmao

Comment: That's actually not what happens: the initial list declaration _does_ have references to those dictionaries, but in the loop you are reassigning the list indices to be new values. Indeed, this would be much easier in C, because I still find references and copies in Python to be quite arbitrary. However, it _would_ work with `NFC[i].update()`, but you would need to change `'teams': NFC[i]` as that is a circular reference.