# What is the maximum length for an attribute name in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm writing a set of python functions that perform some sort of conformance checking on a source code project. I'd like to specify quite verbose names for these functions, e.g.: `check_5_theVersionOfAllVPropsMatchesTheVersionOfTheAutolinkHeader()`

Could such excessively long names be a problem for python? Is there a maximum length for attribute names?

Comment: Please don't do this.  Long names aren't always bad, but they are a code smell.  In this case I would shorten the name and put a more detailed description in a doc string.  Also, I would either log the results verbosely or throw a clearly written exception explaining the failed check.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

[2.3. Identifiers and keywords](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers) from  The Python Language Reference:

> Identifiers are unlimited in length.

---

But you'll be violating [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length) most likely, which is not really cool:

> Limit all lines to a maximum of 79 characters.

Also you'll be violating [PEP-20](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) (the Zen of Python):

> Readability counts.

Comment: well thanks, but for the readability part, I can't let that count: This is exactly what I'm trying to achieve here. The name of the function tells you what it does. If I abbreviate it, it becomes less readable. (will accept your answer in 8 min)

Comment: @AlexanderTobiasHeinrich Your code will be _absolutely unreadable_. Use [docstrings](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/).

Comment: "Fully descriptive" and "readable" are two separate things. Long, long camel-cased strings are the former, not the latter.

Comment: I do use docstrings and I aggree, in general, that long names should be avoided, because they're not easy to read and not easy to remember. I agree with @chepner that there's a difference between descriptiveness and readability - here I wanted a descriptive name. Reason: The function will only be called at a single location in source code and it will be called together with  many other similar functions. By giving long, descriptive names to these functions I release the reader from having to jump to the function definition only to get a glimpse of what they're doing. docstrings don't help here

Comment: If they are only being called once and in one place, just provide comments at that point, rather than trying to embed comments in the names of the attributes.

Comment: @chepner Indeed. I hate it when I encounter things like `AggregateAccountabilityViewManager<AlternateSetupScrollingLoaderView> aggregateAccountabilityViewManagerForAlternateSetupScrollingLoaderViews = new AggregateAccountabilityViewManager<AlternateSetupScrollingLoaderView>();` (as a random Java example) in code. Just because code-completion makes stuff like that a lot easier to write doesn't mean you should.

Comment: @JAB Well, your example mostly shows a huge problem of Java. I mean, long idetifiers are bad, but Java makes even not-very-long identifiers horrible.

Comment: @chepner: why spend an extra line, if the name can carry that information? only to get the warm feeling, I (blindly) adhered the coding guideline?

Comment: The name carries the information poorly. Why are you so set against using comments for their intended purpose?

Comment: @AlexanderTobiasHeinrich Because functionsThatTellYouExactlyWhatTheyDoInCamelCase(areReallyAnnoyingBecauseItAllRunsTogether).

Comment: @chepner: I love comments, if they document a public interface. If they don't I'd rather try to write code that does not need comments.

Comment: @AlexanderTobiasHeinrich I think his point is (and if it isn't I'm making it myself): A single identifier is inferior to comments/docstrings for long descriptions, whole sentences etc. because they impose stupid restrictions on formatting - you can't use spaces, or punctuation, etc. and if you adhere to a particular casing style (which you probably should for consistency) you can't even capitalize half the words properly.

Comment: @AlexanderTobiasHeinrich Nesting of templates in C++/generics in Java isn't the issue here, but using long identifier names does indeed make them less parsable. `LongIdentifierName<LongerIdentifierName<EvenLongerIdentifierName, EvenLongerIdentifierName>, WhyWouldYouEvenDothis<ImAskingYouWhy<AndThisOneIsJustForTheHeckOfIt>>>>`. Even if you break it across lines and use indentation, it's still a lot messier than using decently descriptive yet succinct identifiers and putting a proper description elsewhere (and delnan makes a good point about the (lack of) inline formatting as well).

Comment: Python also gives you the flexibility, especially for something like this, to monkey patch a test harness in to your program.  If you combine the ability to overload (and return any arbitrary type, like, say, `ComparisonResult`) operators with something that attaches metadata to objects and a function that generically generates logging for verifications, you can end up with something like `verify(all_v_props.version == auto_link_header.version)` that will log a nice verbose message for both success or failure.

Comment: @AlexanderTobiasHeinrich Perhaps you should ask the people who would be reading and maintaining your code what they would prefer.

Comment: for this specific project: that would be me. (Anyway: I really appreciate all your comments, even if I may appear a bit stubborn)

Comment: @AlexanderTobiasBockstaller, out of curiosity, are you still the one maintaining that code ten years later?

Answer (score 7):

They could be a problem for the programmer. Keep the function names reasonably short, and use docstrings to document them.

Answer (score 3):

Since attribute names just get hashed and turned in to keys on `inst.__dict__` for 99% of classes you'll ever encounter, there's no real limit on length.  As long as it is hashable, it'll work as an attribute name.  For the other 1% of classes that fiddle with `__setattr__`\ `__getattr__`\ `__getattribute__` in ways that break the guarantee that anything hashable is a valid attribute name though, the previous does not apply.

Of course, as others have pointed out, you will have code style and quality concerns with longer named attributes.  If you are finding yourself needing such long names, it's likely indicative of a design flaw in your program, and you should probably look at giving your data more hierarchical structure and better abstracting and dividing responsibility in your functions and methods.

Comment: You really think that interpreter hashes method names on each invocation?

Comment: Would be more productive if worded `the interpreter doesnt hash method names on each invocation, see ...`

Comment: Unless you are using a JIT or other sort of optimizing or look-ahead interpreter (which to my knowledge CPython is not), yes.

Comment: Not dumb at all.  My understanding is that the CPython interpreter was specifically designed to be as simple to extend as possible, which meant tradeoffs for performance optimization.  Hence why PyPy and the like exist.

Comment: CPython is mostly a simple interpreter, yes, but that does not mean there are no performance optimizations (if there weren't, it would be much slower than it is anyway). Two of those optimizations interact to make sure virtually no attribute lookup actually runs a hash function. (1) The strings for attribute lookup are constant, and hence [interned](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1136826/395760). (2) Strings [remember their hash value](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/stringobject.c#l1272) after the first time they're hashed.

Comment: @delnan Interesting, thanks.  I removed the offending sentence from my answer.

Comment: @delnan Unless you're using run-time reflection, in which case the interpreter won't know what strings to intern until runtime. ...Or so I thought, but it seems attribute-access strings actually are interned either way.

Comment: @JAB It's possible that `getattr` and the like call `intern` on the argument names. I don't know if that's what happens but that would be my guess based on your edit. Good point anyway, as this is an implementation detail and likely to change.

Comment: @delnan It seems they are interned... when using a char* string. http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/object.c#l816 On the other hand, `setattr` does utilize interning for Python strings. http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/object.c#l953

Answer (score 1):

PEP-3131 says that there is no limit to the identifier length. But a specific implementation of Python may decide to limit this length.