# Is there a limit to the length of a function name in python?

Tags: python, function

Every length seems to work, as long as I conform to the rules of defining the function name.
What exactly is the limit or is there even one?

Comment: No official limit. Any implementation limits are implementation details.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the maximum length for an attribute name in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16920835/what-is-the-maximum-length-for-an-attribute-name-in-python)

Comment: Interested in why you're interested.

Comment: No there are no limits on the length, but there are style guides to follow. Still it is up to you on how you will name your functions in your code.

Comment: PEP8: Limit all lines to a maximum of 79 characters. Not one of the favorite PEP guidelines, of course.

Answer (score 8):

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers

They are unlimited. However lines longer than 79 characters violate pep style guides.

Comment: Link to python 3 [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers).

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length