# Can cython optimize python dictionary memory and lookup speed as well?

Tags: python, cython

I have a class which primarily contains the three dicts:

```
class KB(object):

  def __init__(self):

    # key:str value: list of str
    linear_patterns = defaultdict(list)

    # key:str value: list of str        
    nonlinear_patterns = defaultdict(list)

    # key: str value: dict
    pattern_meta_info = {}
    ...
    self.__initialize()

def __initialize(self):
    # the 3 dicts are populated 
    ...
```

The size of the 3 dicts are below:

```
linear_patterns: 100,000
non_linear_patterns: 900,000
pattern_meta_info: 700,000
```

After the program is run and done, it takes about 15 seconds to release the memory. When I reduces the number of the dict sizes above by loading less data in initialization, the memory release is faster, so I judge it's due to these dict sizes that cause memory release slower. The total program takes about 8G memory. Also, after the dicts are built, all operations are lookup, no modifications.

Is there a way to use cython to optimize the 3 data structures above, especially in terms of memory usage? Is there a similar cython dictionary that can replaces the python dicts?

Comment: if your dict is going to contain python objects, then probably you aren't going to beat `dict` which is already implemented in C btw. You could potentially write your own hash-map implementation depending on the nature of your data. E.g., Python `str` objects and `int` objects are highly space inefficienct compared to similar C primitives, e.g. `sys.getsizeof('')` and `sys.getsizeof(1)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga "own hash-map implementation": use cython or python? I don't have much cython experience, but I can learn if it helps here.

Comment: If you don't need all the data all the time, you can use generator functions
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do/69427199#69427199

Comment: You might be able to use C++ `map` or `unordered_map` instead of the Python dict. The one thing that might catch you out - Python strings can be shared (so a string that appears multiple times need not take up more memory) while C++ strings won't be

Comment: @DavidW How to use C++ map in python code?

Comment: @marlon: There are existing wrappers for C++ standard library classes. See [the docs](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html#standard-library). In theory, `std::unordered_map` is what you'd want (it's average case `O(1)` for lookup/insertion/deletion, where `std::map` is `O(log n)` for all operations), but in practice, from what I've seen, `std::unordered_map` isn't well-optimized in most implementations (possibly spec constrained), and usually doesn't beat `std::map` by much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems unlikely that a different dictionary or object type would change much. Destructor performance is dominated by the memory allocator. That will be roughly the same unless you switch to a different malloc implementation.

If this is only about object destruction at the end of your program, most languages (but not Python) would allow you to use call `exit` while keeping the KB object alive. The OS will release the memory much quicker when the process terminates. So why bother? Unfortunately that doesn't work with Python's `sys.exit()` since this merely raises an exception.

Everything else relies on changing the data structure or algorithm. Are your strings highly redundant? Maybe you can reuse string objects by interning them. Keep them in a shared set to use the same string in multiple places. A simple call to `string = sys.intern(string)` is enough. Unlike in earlier versions of Python, this will not keep the string object alive beyond its use so you don't run the risk of leaking memory in a long-running process.

You could also pool the strings in one large allocation. If access is relatively rare, you could change the class to use one large `io.StringIO` object for its contained strings and all dictionaries just deal with `(offset, length)` tuples into that buffer.

That still leaves many tuple and integer objects but those use specialized allocators that may be faster. Also, the length integer will come from the common pool of small integers and not allocate a new object.

A final thought: 8 GB of string data. You sure you don't want a small sqlite or dbm database? Could be a temporary file

Comment: 8GB is all memory used, not the 3 dicts, but they should account for a large part. Do you have a link that tells how to make string objects shared? For example, the str 'test' is shared in two dicts, and they could be key and/or value in the dicts. How to make it shared with less memory? I think making strings shared should be first thing I should try.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136826/what-does-sys-intern-do-and-when-should-it-be-used

Comment: @DavidW thanks for the pointer, which means I should only enclose all string with intern(my_str) when adding it to the dict? That seems to be very. simple? I thought I need to first create some type of hash from each string and then do complex stuff. –

Comment: Apparently sys.intern is clever enough to release unused strings these days. So yes, it's that simple. Keep in mind that strings that don't end up reused will eat a bit more memory because they grow the intern hash table. Plus you spend time calling sys.intern whether it helps you or not.

Comment: I mainly. want to optimize memory usage. I will try.

Comment: @Homer512, just to make sure that the way to use intern() is that my_dict[sys.intern(string1)] = sys.intern(string2). Is that right?

Comment: That should work. Depending on how much your strings are shared it might save a bit of space. If they aren't shared then it'll show things down a little. You'll only find out of you try

Comment: @Homer512: You're incorrect to claim `sys.exit` will do anything to improve cleanup performance. `sys.exit` is implemented using the exception mechanism (it's a thin wrapper that invokes `raise SystemExit`), and the process still does all the normal cleanup (including cleaning up outstanding memory allocations). The only thing that would avoid that cost is `os._exit` (which directly terminates the process without running any outstanding `except`/`finally`/`with` block cleanup), and it's strongly discouraged in most cases (because it bypasses the normal cleanup guarantees).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thanks, I hate it ;-) I rewrote the paragraph to remove the bogus information

Comment: @Homer512: Excellent, up-voted. I suppose if you really wanted to, you could *combine* `sys.exit` and `os._exit` to get the effect you're going for. Just wrap the top-level "main" code with `try:/except SystemExit as e:` then test `e.code` to figure out if it's `int` (use as `os._exit` argument), `str` (send to stderr) or `None` (exit normally with code 0). It would still bypass `atexit` handlers, but you'd unwind the stack normally (invoking `except/finally/with` cleanup), then `os._exit` would skip the final attempts to collect memory. Probably not worth the bother/risk even so. :-)

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yeah, what makes me cautious about ```os._exit```is that it doesn't flush file buffers. So it acts more like C's ```abort``` rather than ```exit```. I'd rather have C's semantics where the stack is not unwinded but the atexit handlers run.