# HashMap and sorting

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap

I am building a trie, each node has a hashmap with sons' value stored, and keys are their name.

I'm using hashmap because, mainly, I need performances instead of sorting, instead I would have used treemap, of course.

Now, I need, just in a function, to sort hash map values by key values (that are strings). Now I'm using iterator to iterate values.

Any suggest?

Thank you

Comment: You should also take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245878/how-do-i-choose-between-a-hash-table-and-a-trie-prefix-tree

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should put the map.keySet in a list sort it and iterate on this list of sorted keys.