# Compare 2 text files in java and write the difference in both separately into another file

Tags: java, performance, testing, automated-tests

This is the code I have written to perform a validation mechanism for comparing 2 files. 
I want to know is there a way to write it in a more performing way, because both of my files can have millions of records in it and this I believe will be slow in those cases.

I am thinking of adding a Hash map, every time I get occurrence of a line in the file, I will add +1 to key value. If not, the value of the key remains 1.
If the record exists in the other map of file 2 , then I remove it from first map. 
If it doesn't, then I add it to the map.
This goes alternation files till end.

**I don't do a line by line comparison because order of the lines may be different in both files.**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader br1 = null;
    BufferedReader br2 = null;
    BufferedWriter br3 = null;
    String sCurrentLine;
    int linelength;
    List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> unexpectedrecords = new ArrayList<String>();

    br1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("expected.txt"));

    br2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("actual.txt"));

    while ((sCurrentLine = br1.readLine()) != null) {
        list1.add(sCurrentLine);
    }
    while ((sCurrentLine = br2.readLine()) != null) {
        list2.add(sCurrentLine);
    }
    List<String> expectedrecords = new ArrayList<String>(list1);

    List<String> actualrecords = new ArrayList<String>(list2);

    if (expectedrecords.size() > actualrecords.size()) {
        linelength = expectedrecords.size();
    } else {
        linelength = actualrecords.size();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < linelength; i++) {
        if (actualrecords.contains(expectedrecords.get(i))) {
            actualrecords.remove(expectedrecords.get(i));
        } else {
            unexpectedrecords.add(actualrecords.get(i));
        }
    }

    br3 = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("c.txt")));
    br3.write("Records which are not present in actual");
    for (int x = 0; x < unexpectedrecords.size(); x++) {
        br3.write(unexpectedrecords.get(x));
        br3.newLine();
    }
    br3.write("Records which are in actual but no present in expected");
    for (int i = 0; i < actualrecords.size(); i++) {
        br3.write(actualrecords.get(i));
        br3.newLine();
    }
    br3.flush();
    br3.close();
}
```

Comment: If it works and is complete, [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) can be a nice place to get high quality answers on ways to improve your code.

Comment: have you try the retainAll method ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/2762137/1811730

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Compare Two Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762093/java-compare-two-lists)

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32565564/4632333

Comment: @dams I had a look at this method. retain doesn't work for me since, I may have the same record twice in the file and I ant both to be taken into consideration. Same applies to removeAll also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## HashMap solution

I thought about it and the HashMap solution is instant. I went ahead and coded up an example of it here.

It runs in 0ms while the arrayLists ran in 16ms for the same dataset

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader br1 = null;
    BufferedReader br2 = null;
    BufferedWriter bw3 = null;
    String sCurrentLine;
    int linelength;

    HashMap<String, Integer> expectedrecords = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    HashMap<String, Integer> actualrecords = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    br1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("expected.txt"));
    br2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("actual.txt"));

    while ((sCurrentLine = br1.readLine()) != null) {
        if (expectedrecords.containsKey(sCurrentLine)) {
            expectedrecords.put(sCurrentLine, expectedrecords.get(sCurrentLine) + 1);
        } else {
            expectedrecords.put(sCurrentLine, 1);
        }
    }
    while ((sCurrentLine = br2.readLine()) != null) {
        if (expectedrecords.containsKey(sCurrentLine)) {
            int expectedCount = expectedrecords.get(sCurrentLine) - 1;
            if (expectedCount == 0) {
                expectedrecords.remove(sCurrentLine);
            } else {
                expectedrecords.put(sCurrentLine, expectedCount);
            }
        } else {
            if (actualrecords.containsKey(sCurrentLine)) {
                actualrecords.put(sCurrentLine, actualrecords.get(sCurrentLine) + 1);
            } else {
                actualrecords.put(sCurrentLine, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    // expected is left with all records not present in actual
    // actual is left with all records not present in expected
    bw3 = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("c.txt")));
    bw3.write("Records which are not present in actual\n");
    for (String key : expectedrecords.keySet()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < expectedrecords.get(key); i++) {
            bw3.write(key);
            bw3.newLine();
        }
    }
    bw3.write("Records which are in actual but not present in expected\n");
    for (String key : actualrecords.keySet()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < actualrecords.get(key); i++) {
            bw3.write(key);
            bw3.newLine();
        }
    }
    bw3.flush();
    bw3.close();
}
```

ex:

**expected.txt**

```
one
two
four
five
seven
eight
```

**actual.txt**

```
one
two
three
five
six
```

**c.txt**

```
Records which are not present in actual
four
seven
eight
Records which are in actual but not present in expected
three
six
```

ex 2:

**expected.txt**

```
one
two
four
five
seven
eight
duplicate
duplicate
duplicate
```

**actual.txt**

```
one
duplicate
two
three
five
six
```

**c.txt**

```
Records which are not present in actual
four
seven
eight
duplicate
duplicate
Records which are in actual but not present in expected
three
six
```

Comment: I would like to have something which takes care of multiple occurrences.

Comment: @jithuPaul - I updated my answer. It will now handle duplicate records. by only removing the first match

Comment: It is not preferable when an algorithm needs to read the complete contents of the files to be compared, into memory. There are line-sequential algorithms which do not run out of memory when processing for example two 10 GB files.

Comment: @jithuPaul I made a hashmap solution which is far quicker than arrayLists

Comment: @Flyingdutchman The problem here is that the input is not guaranteed to be in order and it is also possible to have duplicates so it is unlikely it can be done sequentially.

Comment: Ok - I see the bold line which has been added now above, in the original question. I do strongly advocate for a merge sort of the two files, after they have been concatenated, and subsequently compare each pair of consecutive pair of lines in order to identify all duplicates. The merge-sort algorithm lends itself very well for using the file-system as cache. [Merge-sort explained](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort)

Comment: @Caleb, the hash map thing looks just perfect for my scenario.

Comment: @Caleb Can this be extended to more than 2 files? Ex: multiple files in 2 different folders and the result is also multiple files which need to be created in a third folder.? Could you assist with this please where we mention folders instead of having to mention the exact file names which have to be compared and written to.

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8 you can use `Collection.removeIf(Predicate<T>)`

```
list1.removeIf(line -> list2.contains(line));
list2.removeIf(line -> list1.contains(line));
```

list1 will then contain everything that is NOT in list2 and list2 will contain everything, that is NOT in list1.

Comment: But, this doesn't take care of multiple occurrences of a line. Eg: I have a 3 occurrences of the same line in file A , but only once in file B, I want to see the difference that 2 lines went missing.

Answer (score -1):

On Unix/Linux computers, you can just call `diff`, which has been optimized for speed and memory usage.

The call looks like

```
String listFileDiffs = executeDiff(filenameWithPath1, filenameWithPath2);
```

The method is implemented by:

```
private String executeDiff(String filenameWithPath1, String filenameWithPath2) {
    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
    Process p0;
    Process p1;
    Process p2;
    try {
        p0 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sort " + filenameWithPath1 + " > /tmp/sort1file");
        p0.waitFor();
        p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sort " + filenameWithPath2 + " > /tmp/sort2file");
        p1.waitFor();
        p2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("diff " + "/tmp/sort1file" + " " + "/tmp/sort2file");
        p2.waitFor();
        BufferedReader reader =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p2.getInputStream()));
        String line = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
            output.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("Error: executeCommand ", e);
    }
    return output.toString();
}
```

You can add flags to `diff` in order to give more information regarding all file differences found.

The solution has been adapted to take into account the random order of the lines in each file. The Unix `sort` is being called for each of the two files. The `diff` is subsequently being run.

The Unix commands have matured over decades, and work with a high efficiency.