# BST or hash table dictionary for a spelling checker

Tags: dictionary, hash, binary-search-tree

If I were to implement a word processor's spelling checker, which would be more efficient implementation? The dictionary needs frequent retrievals and occasional insertions. Since there is no maximum number of dictionary items, BST would be a better choice. But it also needs frequent retrievals and a hash table has faster search operation time. What would be the better answer in this case?

Comment: Are you intending to have this spell checker actually offer corrections, or just return a known-word/unknown-word flag for each word?

Comment: That wasn't specified in the question... I guess if you needed to offer corrections, you would neeed to support a fast ordered traversal operations, so a BST would be the best choice.

Comment: I know it wasn't, that's why I asked. It seems like a pretty useless spell checker without corrections. Are you actually making a spell-checker, or is this question just academic? Also, have you read this: http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since there is no maximum number of dictionary items, BST would be a better choice.

IMO, implementing a dictionary using BST would be a bad idea. Trie is the right option for you.

You can find the comparision between hashtable and trie here : [How Do I Choose Between a Hash Table and a Trie (Prefix Tree)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245878/how-do-i-choose-between-a-hash-table-and-a-trie-prefix-tree)