# Efficient Search Algorithm For Specific Data Fields

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, processing-efficiency, memory-efficient

So I am actually been assigned to write algorithms on filtering/searching.

**Task : Filter: search and list objects that fulfill specified attribute(s)**

Say The whole system is a student registration record system.

I have data as shown below. I will need to filter and search by these attributes say search/filter by gender or student name or date of birth etc.

**Student Name
, Gender
, Date Of Birth
, Mobile No**

Is there specific efficient algorithm formula or method for each of these field.

**Example , strings and integers each has their own type of efficient search algorithm right?**

**Here's what I am going to do.**
I am going to code a **binary search algorithm for searching/filtering** based on these fields above.

That's it. But yeah that's easy to be honest.

But I am just curious like what's the proper and appropriate coding approach for a efficient search/filter algorithm for each of these fields will you guys do?

**I will not be using sequential search algorithm obviously** as this **will involve huge data** so I am **not going to iterate each of these data** to downgrade efficiency performance.

**Sequential search algorithm will be used when needed if data is less.**

Answer (score 1):

**Searching** is a very broad topic and it completely depends upon your use case.
while building an efficient Searching algorithm you should take below factors into consideration

- What's the **size** of your data? -is it fixed or it keeps varying
     periodically?
- **How often** you are going to Insert/modify/delete
     your data?
- Is your data **sorted or unsorted**?
- Do you need a **prefix based search** like autosearch,autocomplete,longest prefix search etc?

  Now let's think about the solution/approach

  1. if your data is less and unsorted as you can try **Linear
     Search**(which has O(n)time complexity where "n" is size of your
     data/array)
  2. if your data is already sorted which is not always the case you can
     use **Binary search** as it's complexity is **0(log n)**. if your
     data is not sorted then sorting the data  again takes
     **(n*logn)***~typically if you are using Java,**Arrays.sort()** by default uses Merge sort or Quick sort which is **(nlogn)**.
  3. **if faster retrieval** is the main object you can think of HashMaps or HashMaps.  the elements of Hashmap are indexed by Hashcode, the
     time to search for any element would almost be 1 or constant time(if
     your hash function implementation is good)
  4. **Prefix based search** :since you mentioned about searching by Names,you also have the option of using
     "**Tries**" data structure.

**Tries are excellent option** if you are performing **Insert/Delete/Update** functionalities **frequently** .
Lookup of an elements in a Trie is 0(**k**) where "k" is the length of the string to be searched.

Since you have registration data where insert,update,deletion is common **TRIES Data Structure** is a good option to consider.

Also,check this link to choose between Tries and HashTables [TriesVsMaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245878/how-do-i-choose-between-a-hash-table-and-a-trie-prefix-tree)

Below is the sample representation of Tries(img src:Hackerearth)

[image: image src:HackerEarth]